# Why do PowerShell comparison operators not enumerate collections of size 1?

Tags: powershell

When checking variables and collections of variables for nullity, comparison operators seem to enumerate collections of size 2 or more:

```
> if ( @( $null, $null ) -eq $null ) { $True } else { $False }
True
```

But they do not for collections of size 1:

```
> if ( @( $null ) -eq $null ) { $True } else { $False }
False
```

I'm aware that it's best practice to null-compare using the left-hand side (`$null -eq @( $null )`), but can someone explain what's happening here? I suspect there's something more subtle happening that impacts other code that I write.

Why are these two results different?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following items evaluate to `$false`:

```
@()
0
$null
$false
''
```

---

In your first example:

```
@($null, $null) -eq $null
```

This evaluates to `$null, $null` which is a non-zero collection, so it is `$true`.  You can observe this with the following:

```
[bool]($null, $null)
```

---

In your second example, what you're observing is filtering of an array like the first case, but <s>returning a scalar (instead of an array) since</s> only one item of the array matched the filter:

```
@($null) -eq $null
```

This evaluates to `@($null)` but powershell is evaluating it as a scalar in a boolean context, so it returns `$false`, observed by:

```
[bool]@($null)
```

---

*Footnote: in powershell **v2**, there was a bug with `$null` filtering which spawned the left-hand `$null` comparison.  This bug caused `if/else` blocks to be skipped entirely.*

Answer (score 8):

**tl;dr**

In PowerShell conditionals / implicit Boolean contexts and `[bool]` casts:

- *Single*-element arrays are treated like *scalars*: that is, their one and only element *itself* is interpreted as a Boolean.<sup>[1]</sup>
- *2+*-element arrays are *always* `$true`, irrespective of their content.

---

**With an array as the LHS**, array-aware operators such as `-eq` invariably **also *output* an array**.

Since your array elements are all `$null` and you compare to `$null`, your comparison is an effective *no-op* - e.g., `@( $null ) -eq $null` results in `@( $null )` - and your conditionals are equivalent to:

```bash
[bool] @( $null, $null ) # -> $true - array with 2+ elements is always $True
[bool] @( $null )        # -> $false(!) - treated like: [bool] $null
```

Perhaps surprisingly, **the *implicit Boolean logic* applies *pipeline logic* to an array**:

That is, a *single*-element array is (conceptually) *unwrapped* and its *element* is interpreted as a Boolean.

Therefore, `[bool] @( $null )` is treated the same as `[bool] $null`, which is `$false`.

Generally, **`@( <one-and-only-element> )`** (or `, <one-and-only-element>`) is **treated the same as `<one-and-only-element>` in a Boolean context.**

By contrast, **if an array has *2 or more elements*, it is *always* `$true` in a Boolean context**, even if all its elements would individually be considered `$false`.

---

**Workaround for testing whether an arbitrary array is *empty*:**

Base your conditional on the `.Count` property:

```bash
if ( (<array>).Count ) { $true } else { $false }
```

You could append `-gt 0`, but that's not strictly necessary, because any nonzero value is implicitly `$true`.

Applied to your example:

```bash
PS> if ( ( @($null) -eq $null ).Count ) { $true } else { $false }
True
```

---

**Testing an arbitrary value for being a (scalar) `$null`:**

```bash
if ($null -eq <value>) { $true } else { $false }
```

Note how **`$null` must be used as the *LHS*** in order to prevent the array-filtering logic from taking effect, should `<value>` be an array.

That's also the reason why Visual Studio Code with the PowerShell extension advises "$null should be on the left side of comparisons" if you write something like `$var -eq $null`.

---

[1] **To-Boolean conversion summary**:

- **Among *scalars* (non-collections)**:

  - The following are **implicitly `$false`**:

    - `''`/`""` (empty string)
    - `0` (of any numeric type).
    - `$null`, including the "enumerable null" value indicating the *absence of output* from a command (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76631985/45375) for background information); e.g. both
      `[bool] $null` and `[bool] (Get-ChildItem NoSuchFiles*)` yield `$false`.

      - **Pitfall**: Comparing `$null` or the "enumerable null" to a Boolean *explicitly* with `-eq` is *always `$false`*, even with `$null` as the RHS (despite the RHS normally getting coerced to the type of the LHS):

        ```bash
        # !! -> $false
        # By contrast, `$false -eq [bool] $null` is $true
        $false -eq $null

        # Ditto for the "enumerable null"
        # !! -> $false
        $false -eq (Get-ChildItem NoSuchFiles*)
        ```
  - **Pitfall**: ***Any non-empty* string** is **always `$true`**:

    - e.g., `[bool] 'False'` is `$true`
    - Note that this differs from *explicit string parsing*: `[bool]::Parse('false')` does return`$false` (and `$true` for `'true'`, but recognizes nothing else).
  - **Instances of any other non-collection type** are implicitly **always `$true`**, including of type `[pscustomobject]` and `[hashtable]` (which PowerShell treats as a single object, not as a collection of entries).

    - Unfortunately, this includes types that define explicit `[bool]` .NET conversion operators, meaning that these operators are - mostly - *not* honored; see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71632418/45375).

- **Among *collections*** such as *arrays* (more accurately, collection-like types that implement the **[`IList`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.ilist)** interface - see [the source code](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/eb92b14433ab62edaf0afe95312d9859170efe1d/src/System.Management.Automation/engine/LanguagePrimitives.cs#L1021)):

  - ***Empty* collections** are **always `$false`**.
  - **Pitfall**: ***Single-element* collections** are **evaluated *as that element***:

    - If the one and only element is a *scalar* (non-collection): *its* Boolean value.

      - E.g., `[bool] @(0)` is `$false`, whereas `[bool] @(42)` is `$true`
    - If that element is itself a *collection*: `$true` if it has at least 1 element - *irrespective of what that element is*.

      - E.g., `[bool] (,, $false)` is `$true` (a jagged array: a single-element array whose only element is itself a (single-element) array)
  - **2+-element collections** are ***always* `$true`**, *irrespective of their element values*.

    - E.g., `[bool] @($null, $false)` is `$true`.