# What operator should be used to detect an empty psobject?

Tags: powershell

Using the following example:

```
$test = '{ }' | ConvertFrom-Json
```

How can I detect that $test is empty?

Does not work:

```
$test -eq $null
-not $test
```

This does work, but does not feel right:

```
$test.ToString() -eq ''
```

This is a simplified example, but my use-case is the response I get from a REST api using invoke-restmethod, certain properties come back as empty psobjects.

Comment: How about something like: If ($test -eq "") {Write-Host "It's empty!"} ELSE {Write-Host "It's not empty!"}

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**It *is* the simplest solution to test for an empty (property-less) custom object (`[pscustomobject]`) via its *string representation***, but **you need to use an *expandable string* (string interpolation, `"..."`)** rather than `.ToString()` to obtain it:

```
# Returns $True, if custom object $test is empty, i.e. has no properties
-not "$test"
```

<sup>Note: `-not $test.ToString()` *should* be equivalent, but currently (as of PowerShell Core 6.1) isn't, due to a [*bug*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/6163). With the bug present, *any* `[pscustomobject]` instance returns the *empty string* from`.ToString()`.

Another workaround is to use `.psobject.ToString()`.</sup>

Only an empty (property-less) custom object stringifies to the *empty string* inside an expandable string, and coercing an empty string to a Boolean in PowerShell yields `$False`, whereas any nonempty string yields `$True`.

The alternative is to compare against an empty string *as the LHS*, which implicitly forces the `[pscustomobject]` on the RHS to be stringified:

```
# NOTE: Works ONLY with '' on the LHS.
'' -eq $test
```

A **conceptually clearer approach**, though it relies on the hidden `.psobject` property PowerShell adds to all objects, containing reflection information:

```
0 -eq @($test.psobject.Properties).Count
```

<sup>Note the need to use `@(...)` to force enumeration of the properties so that they can be counted - see next section.</sup>

The above methods are convenient, but if `$test` is a large object with many properties, it can be expensive - though in absolute terms that will propbably rarely matter in practice.

---

A **less expensive, but more obscure solution** is to access the `.psobject.Properties` collection without enumerating *all* its members:

```
# Returns $true, if $test has no properties
-not $test.psobject.Properties.GetEnumerator().MoveNext()
```

The `.psobject.Properties` collection is apparently lazily enumerated and therefore doesn't have a `.Count` property; using `.GetEnumerator().MoveNext()` is therefore a way to limit enumeration to the *first* property, if any.

---

As for **what you tried**:

> ```
> $test -eq $null
> ```

`$test` is still an *object*, even if it happens to have no properties, and an object is by definition never `$null`.

> ```
> -not $test
> ```

PowerShell's implicit to-Boolean conversion treats *any* `[pscustomobject]` instance as `$True`, whether or not it happens to have properties; e.g., `[bool] ([pscustomobject] @{})` yields `$True`.

To see how other data types are coerced to Booleans, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53108138/45375).

Answer (score 3):

Probably **more expensive, but less obscure**; is using the the native [`Get-Member`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-member?view=powershell-6) cmdlet:

```
[Bool]($Test | Get-Member -MemberType NoteProperty)
```

**Note** that `$Test` should not be `$Null` (rather than an empty object) otherwise it will produce an error *(as with using methods on `$Null`)*. To avoid this you might also consider using:

```
$Test -and ($Test | Get-Member -MemberType NoteProperty)
```

Comment: Not cheap, as you state, but conceptually clearer (+1). You can avoid the `$null` proplem more concisely by adding `-ErrorAction Ignore` to the `Get-Member` call: `[Bool]($Test | Get-Member -ErrorAction Ignore -MemberType NoteProperty)` or, as a single command: `[bool] (Get-Member -InputObject $Test -MemberType NoteProperty -ErrorAction Ignore)`

Answer (score 1):

use string tests & test with the $Var on the *right* side of the comparison so that it is coerced to the type on the left. you can also test with the `[string]` methods below ... [*grin*]

```
$Test = '{ }' | ConvertFrom-Json

$Test -eq $Null
$Null -eq $Test
$Test -eq ''
''
'' -eq $Test
[string]::IsNullOrEmpty($Test)
[string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($Test)
```

output ...

```
False
False
False

True
True
True
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me...

```
if ((ConvertTo-Json -Depth 1 $testObj) -eq (ConvertTo-Json @{})) {
    echo 'empty object'
}
```