# Writing to a .js file using PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to write to a .js file based on the contents of a text file (C:\installedApps.txt) using PowerShell.

The `installedApps.txt` file contains the name and version of installed applications on a computer - I want to search `installedApps.txt` for an application name and version and have the result assigned to the `$findAppName` and `$findAppVer` variables respectively.

I then want to write to a .js file IF the Select-String cmdlet is successful in matching the `$appName` and `$appVer` arguments passed into the Check-Install function. See code below:

```
function Check-Install ([string]$appName, [string]$appVer) {

  $findAppName = Get-Content C:\installedApps.txt | Select-String $appName
  $findAppver = Get-Content C:\installedApps.txt | Select-String $appVer

  if ($findAppName -and $findAppVer -eq $true) {
   Set-Content -path $jsFile -Value "var row = getElementById('row-1'); 
   row.classList.add('hidden');"    
   } else { 
     write-host Match Not Found
   }
}

Check-Install -appName "Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client" -appVer "4.6.01103"
```

The `$findAppName` and `$findAppVer` variables aren't returning anything, but not sure where I'm going wrong - the Select-String cmdlet should accept variables(?).

Note: No errors thrown up in the shell

**UPDATE:**

Here's an example of how the installedApps.txt log is formatted:

```
DisplayName     : 7-Zip 18.05 (x64)
Publisher       : Igor Pavlov
InstallDate     : 
DisplayVersion  : 18.05
UninstallString : C:\Program Files\7-Zip\Uninstall.exe

DisplayName     : Adobe Flash Player 31 NPAPI
Publisher       : Adobe Systems Incorporated
InstallDate     : 
DisplayVersion  : 31.0.0.122
UninstallString : 
C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\Macromed\Flash\FlashUtil32_31_0_0_122_Plugin.exe - 
maintain plugin

DisplayName     : Adobe Flash Player 31 PPAPI
Publisher       : Adobe Systems Incorporated
InstallDate     : 
DisplayVersion  : 31.0.0.122
UninstallString : 
C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\Macromed\Flash\FlashUtil32_31_0_0_122_pepper.exe - 
maintain pepperplugin

DisplayName     : Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client
Publisher       : Cisco Systems, Inc.
InstallDate     : 20180906
DisplayVersion  : 4.6.01103
UninstallString : MsiExec.exe /X{58524593-122C-43F0-96E2-A6BCC42E3412}
```

I want to trigger an application install/uninstall (without using the WMI object, as I've read it takes a while and can trigger an installation repair on query) and write to a local web page based on the $findApp results via a .js file to show whether the application is already installed or not.

I'm trying to create a software update script with a front-end written in HTML, CSS and JavaScript for the UI. The script will run on logon across multiple computers in a domain. I'll need to use Ajax to find a way to update the local web page dynamically without a page refresh, but one step at a time.

Comment: You do not return `$findAppName` or `$findAppver`. The variables are only visible in the scope of the function. Can you please clearify the expected and actual behaviour?

Comment: Presumably your file `installedApps.txt` contains AppName and AppVer on one line, yoru two separate select-string might find these also on two separate lines. Better use a RegEx for a match on one line. Also your title doesn't seem to be related to your text/code.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

Note that the assumption is that the input `*.txt` file's lines contain the application name *before* the version number, but it's easy to change that.

```
function Check-Install ([string]$appName, [string]$appVer) {

  if (Select-String -Quiet -Pattern (
         '\b{0}\b{1}\b' -f [regex]::Escape($appName), [regex]::Escape($appVer)
       ) -LiteralPath C:\installedApps.txt
  ) { # if
    Set-Content -path $jsFile -Value "var row = getElementById('row-1');
    row.classList.add('hidden');"
  } else {
     write-host 'No match.'
  }

}

Check-Install -appName "Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client" -appVer "4.6.01103"
```

- `Select-String -Quiet` outputs only a `[bool]` value that reflects in the abstract whether the pattern matched (at least) one line.
- `[regex]::Escape()` is used to escape the application name and version for use in a regex so that they're treated as *literals* when matching.
- `'\b{0}\b{1}\b' -f ...` builds a single regex (string) from the escaped values to look for *both* values on the *same* line, using assertion `\b` to ensure that they only match at word boundaries (and not also inside larger words).
- Note how `Select-String` can directly accept a filename operand, via the `-LiteralPath` or `-Path` parameters, which is both shorter and more efficient.

---

As for **what you tried**:

> ```
> $findAppName = Get-Content C:\installedApps.txt | Select-String $appName
> $findAppver = Get-Content C:\installedApps.txt | Select-String $appVer
> ```

- You're looking for the name and version *separately*, which means that you may find a match for a version number that pertains to a *different* application, for instance.
- `$findAppName` and `$findAppver` are either "nothing" (effectively, `$null`), if no match is found, or instances of type [`[MatchInfo]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.powershell.commands.matchinfo])

> ```
> $findAppName -and $findAppVer -eq $true
> ```

- As stated, these variables aren't *Booleans*, so comparing them with `-eq` to `$true` is pointless.

Apart from that, due to PowerShell's [operator precedence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/reference/5.1/Microsoft.PowerShell.Core/about/about_Operator_Precedence), your statement would be parsed as `$findAppName -and ($findAppVer -eq $true)`, i.e., the explicit `-eq` comparison is only applied to the *second* variable, which in your case *always* returns `$false`.

That said, you could have relied on PowerShell's *implicit* Boolean logic<sup>[1]</sup> (leaving the problem of searching for the terms separately aside):

```
$findAppName -and $findAppVer
```

This would have evaluated to `$true` if both `$findAppName` and `$findAppVer` contained `[MatchInfo]` instance(s), i.e., if both `Select-String` calls had found at least 1 match.

---

<sup>[1] For a summary of PowerShell's implicit to-Boolean conversion logic, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53108138/45375).</sup>