# How can I incorporate arrays to compare one value to all values in array?

Tags: powershell

I'm new to scripting and struggling with implementing some concepts. I've got a PowerShell script working that will take in input from the user and store it into several variables. It will then look at a .csv file and only output rows where the several inputs from the user is not like the value in a specified column.

For example, if I've got a .csv file that contains:

```
value1, value2, value3
data1, data2, data3
data1, data2, data3
data1, data5, data3
data1, data2, data3
```

And I ask to output the rows where value2 is not like data5 I get the following as output:

```
value1, value2, value3
data1, data2, data3
data1, data2, data3
data1, data2, data3
```

Here's the current code I have that is working:

```
$path = Read-Host 'What is the file share path?'

$filteredvalue = Read-Host 'What value would you like to filter out?'
$filteredvalue2 = Read-Host 'What second value would you like to filter out?'
$filteredvalue3 = Read-Host 'What second value would you like to filter out?'
$filteredvalue4 = Read-Host 'What second value would you like to filter out?'
$filteredvalue5 = Read-Host 'What second value would you like to filter out?'
$filteredvalue6 = Read-Host 'What second value would you like to filter out?'
$filteredvalue7 = Read-Host 'What second value would you like to filter out?'


$file1 = $path

$filtered = Import-Csv -Path $file1 | where {$_.IdentityReference -notlike $filteredvalue -and $_.IdentityReference -notlike $filteredvalue2 -and $_.IdentityReference -notlike $filteredvalue3 -and $_.IdentityReference -notlike $filteredvalue4 -and $_.IdentityReference -notlike $filteredvalue5 -and $_.IdentityReference -notlike $filteredvalue6 -and $_.IdentityReference -notlike $filteredvalue7}

$file2 = "${path}_filtered.csv"

$filtered | Export-Csv -Path $file2 -NoTypeInformation
```

This works but is not the best solution as I have to specify in the code how many values I'll be filtering out. I would like to use arrays to prevent having to create all the variables for the values.

Here's what I've tried so far but no luck:

```
$path = Read-Host 'What is the file share path?'

$Reponse = 'Y'
$filteredvalue = $Null
$filteredvalues = @()

Do 
{ 
    $filteredvalue = Read-Host 'What value would you like to filter out?'
    $Response = Read-Host 'Would you like to filter out additional values? (y/n)'
    $filteredvalues += $filteredvalue
}
Until ($Response -eq 'n')


$file1 = $path

$filtered = Import-Csv -Path $file1 | where {for($i = 0; $i -le $filteredvalues.GetUpperBound(0); $i++) {$_.IdentityReference -ne $filteredvalues[$i]}}


$file2 = "${path}_filtered.csv"

$filtered | Export-Csv -Path $file2 -NoTypeInformation
```

The output remains the same and nothing gets filtered out.

Comment: You should use the `-notin` operator. The syntax is `value -notin array`

Answer (score 1):

PowerShell offers [array-containment comparison operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators#containment-operators) `-contains` and, since v3, also `-in` - they differ only in whether the input array goes on the LHS (`-contains`) or RHS (`-in`).

As most operators in PowerShell, they also exist in *negated* form, i.e. `-notcontains` and `-notin`.

Applied to your code:

```
$filtered = Import-Csv $file1 | Where-Object IdentityReference -notin $filteredValues
```

---

As for **what you tried**:

As an aside: it's easier to use `$filteredvalues.Count - 1` instead of `$filteredvalues.GetUpperBound(0)`.

`where` (`Where-Object`) selects (passes through) input objects based on whether the output from the script block `{ ... }` evaluates to `$true`.

Your `for`-loop code returns an *array* of Booleans, indicating *for each filter value* whether the input object's `.IdentityReference` matches that value.

Therefore, with 2 or more filter values, you'll end up with an array that contains at least *1* `$true` value, and any such array is invariably interpreted as `$true` overall.

For instance:

```
PS> [bool] ($false, $true)
True
```

For an overview of how PowerShell implicitly evaluates object as Booleans (to-Boolean conversion), see the bottom half of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53108138/45375).

For your loop approach to have worked, you would have had to return `$false` as a scalar as soon as a filter value matched, and default to `$true` otherwise (note the use of `foreach` to enumerate the array elements more conveniently):

```
$filtered = Import-Csv -Path $file1 | where {
  foreach ($filteredValue in $filteredValues) {
    if ($_.IdentityReference -eq $filteredValue) { return $false }
  }
  return $true
}
```