# How to iterate over a certain pattern of file names to use it on FFMPEG and PowerShell

Tags: powershell, video, ffmpeg, iteration

I'm fairly inexperienced with PowerShell and I use it in certain occasions when I need to have total control of the conversion needed.
So, I am facing a problem where I have a collection of 20 videos. All share the same number pattern from 1300 to 1319, and I want to convert the whole collection of "MOV" files into "MP4" files using this command:
`ffmpeg -i my-video-1300.mov -vcodec h264 -acodec mp2 my-video-1300.mp4`

Is there a way to use a Regular Expression, wildcard, or whatever name is given to simply create a single line conversion command.
My idea of what it "should look like" is:
`ffmpeg -i my-video-13[00-19].mov -vcodec h264 -acodec mp2 my-video-13[00-19].mp4`

Of course this last line doesn't work, but I would like to learn the correct way of doing it.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter my-video-*.mov |
Where-Object {
  if ($_.BaseName -match '-(\d+)$') {     
    $number = [int] $Matches[1]
    $number -ge 1300 -and $number -le 1319    
  }
} | 
ForEach-Object { 
  ffmpeg -i $_.FullName -vcodec h264 -acodec mp2 ($_.FullName -replace '\.mov$', '.mp4')
}
```

- `Get-ChildItem -Filter my-video-*.mov` pre-filters candidate files efficiently using a simple *wildcard pattern*.
- The `Where-Object` script block then extracts the number from the base file name via a [*regex*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_regular_expressions) (regular expression) and the [`-match` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators#-match), and checks if the number is in the range of interest.

  - Outputting `$true` from the script block (implicitly from the Boolean range-checking expression, `$number -ge ...`) causes the file at hand to be included and passed down the pipeline.
  - Note that producing *no* output is implicitly interpreted as `$false`, based on [PowerShell's too-Boolean conversion logic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53108138/45375).
- The `ForEach-Object` script block is then only executed for the files of interest.

  - `($_.FullName -replace '\.mov$', '.mp4')` derives the output file name from the input file name by replacing the `.mov` extension with `.mp4`, using a regex and the [`-replace` operator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40683667/45375).