# using if statement to check if variable is null returns incorrectly

Tags: powershell, variables, error-handling

I have a powershell script i have created and there is step where it tries to import a module if it is not already imported.

```
Try {
    Import-Module -Name 'ModuleName' -ErrorAction Stop -ErrorVariable ModFail             
}
Catch {
    Write-Error "Module failed to be loaded."
}
```

later in the script i am trying to check if module failed to be imported but checking the error variable.  For other variables not being set through the errorvariable parameter i just use the below to check if its null.

```
If ($null -eq $var) {
    Do stuff
}
```

But doing so with the variable i have set using errorvariable is not working.

```
if ($null -ne $Modfail) {
    Do stuff
}
```

when testing if the variable is actually null the above evaluates to true.  This is the opposite of what i want.  When i run the variable it is indeed null and running

```
$modfail | Gm
```

fails because it is empty.  Why is this happening?  If i set the variable outside of the errorvariable parameter or do not set it all it returns correct.  Even if it had whitespace it should return as string correct when piping to Get-Member?

Comment: It work fine as far as I can see when testing your example. 
Are you calling `$modfail` in a different scope (outside/inside a different function, module, other) ? You can always remove -ErrorVariable and put this as the first line of your catch block `$Modfail = $_` to see if it makes a difference.

Comment: No its all inside the same main if block, this is just a sub if block to check if the variable is null or not before doing other work.  Just ran it again and got the same results.  $null -eq  $ModFail returns False, $null -ne $modFail returns True, even though its null.  I did find that running [String]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($modFail) Returns correctly but still am curios as to why the other way doesnt work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- The `-ErrorVariable` [common parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_CommonParameters), like all `-*Variable` common parameters, reports the collected output from the relevant stream as a [`System.Collections.ArrayList`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.ArrayList) instance.
- (Unless there's a *syntactic* problem with the invocation), a `System.Collections.ArrayList` is *always* created and assigned to the specified variable, even if *no* objects are output to the  targeted stream; that is, in the case of `-ErrorAction`, if no errors occur, an *empty* `System.Collections.ArrayList` is created - which is distinct from `$null`.

Therefore, `if ($null -ne $Modfail) ...` is not the right test, as it will *always* return `$true` (any object is by definition not `$null`, irrespective of its type or content).

Instead, use `if ($Modfail.Count -gt 0) ...` or, more simply, rely on the fact that an empty collection is implicitly coerced to `$false`<sup>[1]</sup>: `if ($Modfail) ...`

---

As for:

> `$modfail | Get-Member` fails because it is empty. Why is this happening?

Whenever you send a collection through the *pipeline*, it is *enumerated*. 
Enumerating an *empty* array enumerates *nothing*, in which case `Get-Member` (rightfully) complains about missing input.

(If the array isn't empty, you should see information about `System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord`, the type of the elements stored in `$ModFail`).

If you want to inspect the *collection itself* with `Get-Member`, use 
`Get-Member -InputObject $Modfail` - you'll see that it is of type  `System.Collections.ArrayList` (as a non-generic collection, its elements have no predetermined type).

---

<sup>[1] Note that *single-element* collections *may* be coerced to `$false` as well, depending on the value of that single element; however, with the collections created by `-ErrorVariable`, which contain [`System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord) instances when nonempty, that is not a concern; for background information, see the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53108138/45375).</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You can check the truthiness of the error variable instead:

```
if( !$ModFail ){
  # Do stuff if the module loaded correctly
}
```

You don't want to check `if( $null -eq $ModFail )` because the `-ErrorVariable` is always set to a collection, albeit an empty one if no error occurs. The collection itself is not null, so this check will always return `$true`.

Since it *is* a collection, you *can* also check the `Count` of the `-ErrorVariable` to determine if any errors exist in the collection. Using `$ModFail` in your case:

```
if( $ModFail.Count -eq 0 ){
  # Do stuff if the module loaded correctly
}
```

Comment: To summarize the discussion: the `-eq` test with an array-valued LHS works as designed, though it may be surprising: comparison operators such as `-eq` act as _array filters_ with an array-valued LHS, so you get the _subarray of matching items_ as a result, not a Boolean. That `$null -eq (@() *>&1)` is `$true` while `$null -eq (@())` is (rightfully) not, smells like a bug - see [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/11598). I suggest cleaning up the other comments here (I've already removed mine).