# How does one add output from a cmdlet to an array?

Tags: arrays, powershell

I am trying to determine if specific Windows hotfixes are installed on our Windows servers. I am quite new to PowerShell scripting and this is what I have so far:

```
$servers = Get-ADComputer -Filter {(OperatingSystem -like "Windows Server 2019*") -and (enabled -ne $false)} -Property *
$result = @()
ForEach ($item in $servers) {
    $testhotfix = Get-HotFix -Id KB4534310,KB4534314,KB4534283,KB4534288,KB4534297,KB4534309,KB4534271,KB4534273 -ComputerName $item.Name | `
    select $item.Name,$item.CanonicalName,$item.OperatingSystem
    $result += $testhotfix
}
$result | Export-Csv -Path C:\Users\user1\Desktop\Servers.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

The CSV file that is created includes one line with the information I'm looking for, followed by several lines of commas, like so:

[Script Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mYGg3.jpg)

> "SERVER1","somedomain.com/Servers/Non-Prod/New_Server_Staging/SERVER1","Windows Server 2019 Standard"
>   ,,
>   ,,
>   ,,
>   ,,
>   ,,
>   ,,
>   ,,
>   ,,
>   ,,
>   ,,
>   ,,
>   ,,
>   ,,
>   ,,
>   ,,
>   ,,
>   ,,
>   ,,
>   ,,
>   ,,
>   ,,

We have several servers with at least one of the hotfixes installed. How do I add each server to the *$result* array?

Thank you

Comment: As an aside: While seductively convenient, it's best to [avoid the use of script blocks (`{ ... }`) as `-Filter` arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44184818/45375).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking:

> `select $item.Name,$item.CanonicalName,$item.OperatingSystem`

should be:

> `select Name, CanonicalName, OperatingSystem`

That is, **you need to pass the property *names* (e.g., `Name`), not the current input object's property *values* (e.g., `$item.Name`)** to `select` (the [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object)cmdlet).

The net effect is that `Select-Object` creates custom objects whose properties are (mistakenly) named for the property *values* and themselves have *no value*, given that the input objects have no such properties.
This explains the output you saw.

**However, the bigger problem is that even that won't work, given that the property names relate to the `$item` object, not to the objects output by `Get-HotFix`, which are the ones `select` operates on.**

As it turns out, what you really need is to **use the `Get-HotFix` call as a *conditional*, so as to only write a CSV row for the computer at hand if *at least one* of the specified hotfixes is installed**:

```
$hotfixIds = 'KB4534310', 'KB4534314', 'KB4534283', 'KB4534288', 'KB4534297', 'KB4534309', 'KB4534271', 'KB4534273'

if (0 -ne (Get-HotFix -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Id $hotfixIds -ComputerName $item.Name).Count)  {
  $result += $item | select Name, CanonicalName, OperatingSystem
}
```

Note:

- Note how it is now `$item` (the computer at hand) that is piped to `select`, to ensure that *its* properties are extracted (in the form of a custom object with these properties).
- You could omit `0 -eq` altogether and rely on PowerShell's implicit to-Boolean conversion, where *any nonzero number* evaluates to `$true` (see the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53108138/45375) for a summary of all rules.

  - If instead you want to test for *all* of the specified hotfixes being installed, replace `0 -ne` with `$hotfixIds.Count -eq`.
- `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` silences the errors from computers where *none* of the specified hotfixes are installed; you could examine the automatic `$Error` collection afterwards, or use `-ErrorVariable err` to collect all command-specific errors in variable `$err`.

Also, your overall command can be greatly streamlined - see the bottom section.

---

A solution for a *different* scenario, that may be of interest as well:

#### If you wanted **to *combine* properties from the `Get-HotFix` output objects with properties from the `$item` objects** (representing the computer at hand):

The following command:

- selects *all* properties from the `Get-HotFix` output objects (`-Property *`)
- *adds* the properties of interest from the current `$item`, using [calculated properties](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39861920/45375)

```
# Additional 'KB...' values omitted for brevity.
Get-HotFix -Id KB4534310, KB4534314 -ComputerName $item.Name | 
  Select-Object -Exclude Name -Property *,
                  @{ n = 'Name'; e = { $item.Name } },
                  @{ n = 'CanonicalName'; e = { $item.CanonicalName } },
                  @{ n = 'OperatingSystem'; e = { $item.OperatingSystem } }
```

Note that `-Exclude Name` excludes the `Name` property from the input objects (`Get-HotFix` output objects that have such a property, but it is *empty*), so that `Name` can be added as a property containing the computer name.

---

#### As for what you tried:

Aside from the `Select-Object` property-name problem mentioned above, your major problem was that you expected a pipeline segment as a *conditional*, which is not how pipelines work:

> `Get-HotFix ... | select ...`

The above simply sends `Get-HotFix`'s *output objects* to `select` (`Select-Object`), which then *unconditionally* processes them (and, as stated, looks for properties with the given names *on these objects*).

Now, if `Get-HotFix` produced *no* output, then conditional logic applies implicitly: the `select` command would then simply not be invoked.

Conversely, if `Get-HotFix` produces *multiple* outputs, `select` would be invoked *on each*.

That is, if we had naively tried to correct your command from:

> `Get-HotFix ... | select ...`

to:

`Get-HotFix ... | ForEach-Object { $item | select ... }`

you would have potentially created *multiple* output objects per computer, namely whenever a given computer happens to have more than one among the given hotfixes installed.

---

#### A streamlined version of your (corrected) command:

Your command can be streamlined to use a *single* pipeline only, without the need for aux. variables:

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter '(OperatingSystem -like "Windows Server 2019*") -and (enabled -ne $false)' -Property * |
  ForEach-Object {
    if (0 -ne (Get-HotFix -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -ComputerName $item.Name -Id KB4534310,KB4534314,KB4534283,KB4534288,KB4534297,KB4534309,KB4534271,KB4534273).Count) {
      $item | select Name, CanonicalName, OperatingSystem
    }
  } | Export-Csv -Path C:\Users\user1\Desktop\Servers.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Note:

- If you *end* a line with `|`, you do *not* need a trailing `` ` `` to signal line continuation.

  - PowerShell [Core] v7.0+ now also allows placing `|` at the *start of the very next line*.
- A single-quoted string (`'...'`) is used instead of a script block (`{ ... }`) to pass the `-Filter` argument, because tt's best to [avoid the use of script blocks (`{ ... }`) as `-Filter` arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44184818/45375).
- The output custom object instances created with `$item | select Name, CanonicalName, OperatingSystem` are sent directly to the pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a PSCustomObject.

```
    $array = foreach($item in $obj)
    {
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            Name = $item.Name
            CanonicalName = $item.CanonicalName
            OS = $item.OperatingSystem
        }
    }
```

Comment: While that is a useful technique for more advanced scenarios, in your scenario `$obj | select Name, CanonicalName, OperatingSystem` is sufficient. (And neither form solves the OP's problem by itself.)