# Powershell if statement

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

In one of my servers we have an program that we need to update each month, this program is running on a terminal server.

My basic script is working (it's very simple):

```
Get-SmbOpenFile |where {$_.Path -eq "D:\Shares\Programs\test.exe"} |select ClientUserName, path |ft -autosize

pause
```

But i'am trying to make it more "smarter" so I've tried to use the IF statement:

First test:

```
$open = Get-SmbOpenFile |where {$_.Path -eq "D:\Shares\Programs\test.exe"} |`
select ClientUserName, path |ft -autosize



if ($open -eq "true")
{ write-host "showing open files"
}

elseif ($open -eq "false")
{ "All cloesd"
}

pause
```

Second test:

```
$open = Get-SmbOpenFile |where {$_.Path -eq "D:\Shares\Programs\test.exe"} |`
select ClientUserName, path |ft -autosize


if ($open -eq $true)
{
 write-host "showing open files"
}

elseif ($open -eq $false)
{ 
"All cloesd"
}
```

I've also tried to define the variable in that way:

```
$open = Get-SmbOpenFile |where {$_.Path -eq "D:\Shares\Programs\test.exe"}
```

I'am not getting actually any output at all when i use the IF statement.

Thanks a lot for your help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- **Only ever use `Format-*` cmdlets such as `ft` (`Format-Table`) for *display formatting*; never use them if data must be *programmatically processed***.
  `Format-*` cmdlets output *formatting instructions*, not *data* - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55174715/45375).
- Even with `| ft -autosize` removed, **you shouldn't compare `$open` to `$true` or `$false`**, because such an explicit comparison will not generally work as intended if the LHS isn't already a *Boolean* (type `[bool]`)<sup>[1]</sup>; instead, **take advantage of PowerShell's *implicit* to-Boolean conversion** - see the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53108138/45375).
- Your `if` branch doesn't actually *output* `$open`; it only outputs a `Write-Host` status message to the display.

To put it all together:

```
$open = Get-SmbOpenFile | 
          Where-Object {$_.Path -eq "D:\Shares\Programs\test.exe"} |
            Select-Object ClientUserName, Path

if ($open) {
  Write-Host "showing open files"
  $open  # output the result
}
else {
  Write-Host "all closed"
}
```

`Select-Object` returns either:

- a `[pscustomobject]` instance<sup>[2]</sup> (a custom object with properties `.ClientUserName` and `.Path`)

  - Any `[pscustomobject]` instance - regardless of its structure - evaluates to `$true` in a Boolean context.
- or "nothing" (technically, `[System.Management.Automation.Internal.AutomationNull]::Value`), if the `Where-Object` cmdlet didn't find the specified path in `Get-SmbOpenFile`'s output.

  - "Nothing" evaluates to `$false` in a Boolean context.

Again, see the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53108138/45375) for the complete set of rules of implicit to-Boolean conversion.

---

<sup>[1] Notably, a non-primitive object as the LHS always yields `$false` when compared to `$true` (though not with the operands reversed); e.g., `(Get-Item /) -eq $true`; also, any nonzero number that isn't exactly `1` will indicate `$false`; e.g.: `2 -eq $true`. Additionally, with an *array-valued* LHS, `-eq` acts as *filter*, returns the *subarray of matching items* (e.g., `(1, 2, 1) -eq $true` returns `1, 1`.</sup>

<sup>[2] In general, `Select-Object` can return *multiple* objects, in which case `$open` would receive an`[object[]]`-typed *array* of `[pscustomobject]` instances. An array with 2 or more elements is *always* `$true` in a Boolean context.</sup>

Comment: I appreciate the nice feedback, @RoadRunner.