# Power Shell Get Service Issue

Tags: powershell

Hi I need to get a script that will do the following:

1. Check if a service exists
2. If the service doesn't exist run my script
3. If the service exists do nothing

Here is what I have but it's not working for me:

```
    $service = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Service -Filter "Name='servicename'"
if($service.Status -eq $NULL)
{
$CLID = $inclid
New-Item -Path "c:\" -Name "folder" -ItemType "directory"
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://something.com\setup.exe -OutFile c:\folder\swibm#$CLID#101518#.exe
$installer = "swibm#$CLID#101518#.exe"
Start-Process -FilePath $installer -WorkingDirectory "C:\folder"
}
else
{
Write-Host "Client Already Installed"
}
```

If I run `$service.Status` alone I get an "OK" returned. Under this condition I would need the script to stop and run the else section. I only want this script to run if `$service.Status` returns nothing. Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: Is this approach any good? `if(Get-Service -ea SilentlyContinue -Name servicename){"exits"}else{"nope"}`

Comment: It works fine for me. You may try putting $null on the left side `If($null -eq $services.status)`

Comment: @DougMaurer Yep this fixed it! Did I miss something in the documentation? I didn't think my order was wrong....weird.

Comment: As an aside: The CIM cmdlets (e.g., `Get-CimInstance`) superseded the WMI cmdlets (e.g., `Get-WmiObject`) in PowerShell v3 (released in September 2012). Therefore, the WMI cmdlets should be avoided, not least because PowerShell [Core] (version 6 and above), where all future effort will go, doesn't even _have_ them anymore. For more information, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54508009/45375).

Comment: @mklement0 Thank you I'm always looking for better ways of doing things I unfortunately have to support a very large array of devices that are not all standardized.

Answer (score 2):

You may try putting $null on the left hand side of the comparison.

```
If($null -eq $services.status)
```

[Here](https://evotec.xyz/the-curious-case-of-null-should-be-on-the-left-side-of-equality-comparisons-psscriptanalyzer/#:%7E:text=%24null%20is%20a%20scalar.,operators%20return%20a%20Boolean%20value.&text=The%20only%20way%20to%20reliably,a%20scalar%20comparison%20is%20performed.) is a nice write up discussing it

Comment: Thank you this is very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Simpler way to check if service exists:

```
if( Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Service -Filter "Name='servicename'" ) {
    # Service exists
}
else {
    # Service doesn't exist
}
```

... or use the `Get-Service` cmdlet:

```
if( Get-Service -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Name servicename ) {
    # Service exists
}
else {
    # Service doesn't exist
}
```

Comment: Thank you I've updated to use `Get-Service` this is much cleaner. Do you know if this method would be considered best practice as in reference to the above poster saying I should be using `Get-CimInstance` ?

Comment: Also I'm I right in that `if( Get-Service -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Name servicename )` is looking to see if the service exists and if true it will preform the `if` statement otherwise if the service doesn't exist it would prefom the `else` statement?

Comment: @L04D1NG The approach in this answer takes advantage of PowerShell's implicit to-Boolean conversions; a non-primitive object such as what `Get-WmiObject` and `Get-Service` return is implicitly `$true`, whereas the _absence_ of output is implicitly `$false`. This shorthand approach is very convenient and works robustly in this case, but, generally speaking, there are pitfalls: see the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53108138/45375) for a summary of the rules.

Comment: @L04D1NG I think `Get-Service` could be considered "best practice", because it is a built-in PowerShell cmdlet, specifically made for this task. This makes your code cleaner and propably also has better, more specific error handling.