# Powershell compare items for order when some are optional

Tags: powershell

I have some XML    with a number of `<task>` nodes that can contain a combination of four child nodes in this order; `<rules>`, `<preprocess>`, `<process>`, `<postprocess>`.

`<process>` is mandatory, but the other three are optional. I need to validate this XML before using it to instantiate my Task object, and I can't use XSD because XSD 1.0 doesn't support some of the other things I have going on in the XML.

My thinking is this. I can convert the node names to a list `$providedData`, and also have a list `$requiredOrder` with the four node names in the required order, then duplicate that as a list `$workingOrder`. Loop through the requiredOrder and any item that isn't in `$providedData` is removed from `$workingOrder`. Now I have `$workingOrder` with the same items as `$providedData`, but in the order defined by `$requiredOrder`. Now a comparison tells me if `$providedData` is correctly ordered. So...

```
$requiredOrder = @('rules', 'preprocess', 'process', 'postprocess')
$providedData = @('preprocess', 'process')

CLS
$workingOrder = [System.Collections.Generic.List[String]]::new()
$workingOrder.AddRange([System.Collections.Generic.List[String]]$requiredOrder)
$providedOrder = [System.Collections.Generic.List[String]]::new()
$providedOrder.AddRange([System.Collections.Generic.List[String]]$providedData)
foreach ($item in $requiredOrder) {
    if ($providedOrder -notContains $item) {
        $workingOrder.Remove($item) > $null
    }
}
if (Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $workingOrder -DifferenceObject $providedOrder) {
    Write-Host "Correct"
} else {
    Write-Host "Incorrect"
}
```

I know I can't use the -eq operator, but I thought Compare-Object would work here. No dice, I get Incorrect. But if I just dump `$workingOrder` and `$providedOrder` to the console, they are (visually) the same.

So, two questions:

1: What am I doing wrong in my comparison here?

2: Is there a much better way to do this?

Interesting...
`if (($workingOrder -join ',') -eq ($providedOrder -join ',')) {` works.
I would still like to know if there is a better way, or a way to get Compare-Object to work. But I can proceed with this for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To compare whether two same-typed collections are equal, both in content and order, I like to use [`Enumerable.SequenceEqual()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.sequenceequal):

```
function Test-NodeOrder 
{
  param([string[]]$Nodes)

  $requiredOrder = @('rules', 'preprocess', 'process', 'postprocess')
  $mandatory = @('process')

  $matchingNodes = $Nodes.Where({$_ -in $requiredOrder})

  if($missing = $mandatory.Where({$_ -notin $matchingNodes})){
    Write-Warning "The following mandatory nodes are missing: [$($missing -join ', ')]"
    return $false
  }

  $orderedNodes = $requiredOrder.Where({$_ -in $matchingNodes})

  if(-not [System.Linq.Enumerable]::SequenceEqual([string[]]$matchingNodes, [string[]]$orderedNodes)){
    Write-Warning "Wrong order provided - expected [$($orderedNodes -join ', ')] but got [$($matchingNodes -join ', ')]"
    return $false
  }

  return $true
}
```

Output:

```
PS C:\> $providedData = @('preprocess', 'process')
PS C:\> Test-NodeOrder $providedData
True
PS C:\> $providedData = @('preprocess')
PS C:\> Test-NodeOrder $providedData
WARNING: The following mandatory nodes are missing: [process]
False
PS C:\> $providedData = @('preprocess', 'process', 'rules')
PS C:\> Test-NodeOrder $providedData
WARNING: Wrong order provided - expected [rules, preprocess, process] but got [preprocess, process, rules]
False
```

Comment: Aha, that's the kind of "better" I was thinking might exist. I wonder at what point my code is so much .NET that I might as well refactor to C#. :)

Comment: That's for you to gauge and decide :) The question I'd be asking is: _why not just **correct** the order in the XML file if all mandatory child nodes are there_? :)

Comment: To be honest there is a part of me that is tempted to just ignore the order in the XML since I can code to handle the nodes in the correct order, even if they aren't provided in that order. But I kind of want to require the correct order in the XML to help the folks providing the XML understand how it works. In the long run I will provide a GUI and ensure correct order. But I am so far behind schedule I can't do that now, and that's also what keeps me from also adding code to fix the XML. Path of least resistance is an error that lets the people creating the XML also maintain it. For now. :)

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems with your code:

- You need to *invert* your success-test logic when calling [`Compare-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/compare-object).
- In order to compare two arrays for not only containing the *same elements*, but also *in the same order* (sequence equality), you need to use `-SyncWindow 0`.

Therefore:

```
if (-not (Compare-Object -SyncWindow 0 $workingOrder $providedOrder)) {
  'Correct'
} else {
  'Incorrect'
}
```

As for the success-test logic:

[`Compare-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Compare-Object)'s output doesn't indicate *success* of the comparison; instead, it outputs *the objects that differ*.

Given PowerShell's [implicit to-Boolean conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53108138/45375), using a `Compare-Object` call *directly* as an `if` conditional *typically* means: if there *are* differences, the conditional evaluates to `$true`, and vice versa.

Since `Compare-Object` with `-SyncWindow 0` outputs at least *two* difference objects (one pair for each array position that doesn't match) and since a 2+-element array is *always* `$true` when coerced to a `[bool]`, you can simply apply the `-not` operator on the result, which reports `$true` if the `Compare-Object` call had *no* output (implying the arrays *were* the same), and `$false` otherwise.

---

**Optional reading: Performance comparison between `Compare-Object -SyncWindow 0` and `[System.Linq.Enumerable]::SequenceEqual()`:**

[Mathias R. Jessen's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64855082/45375) shows a LINQ-based alternative for **sequence-equality testing** based on the **[`System.Linq.Enumerable.SequenceEqual`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Linq.Enumerable.SequenceEqual)** method, which **generally performs much better**  than `Compare-Object -SyncWindow 0`, though with occasional invocations with smallish array sizes that may not matter.

The following performance tests illustrate this, based on averaging `10` runs with `1,000`-element arrays.

The absolute timings, measured on a macOS 10.15.7 system with PowerShell 7.1, will vary based on many factors, but the `Factor` column should give a sense of relative performance.

Note that the `Compare-Object -SyncWindow 0` call is fastest *only* on the *very first invocation* in a session; after `[System.Linq.Enumerable]::SequenceEqual()` has been called once in a session, calling it is internally optimized and becomes much faster than the `Compare-Object` calls.
That is, if you simply *re-run* the tests in a session, `[System.Linq.Enumerable]::SequenceEqual()` will be the fastest method by far, along the lines of the 2nd group of results below:

```
--- 1,000 elements: ALL-positions-different case:

Factor Secs (1-run avg.) Command                                                              TimeSpan
------ ----------------- -------                                                              --------
1.00   0.006             -not (Compare-Object $a1 $a2 -SyncWindow 0 | Select-Object -first 1) 00:00:00.0060075
1.59   0.010             [Linq.Enumerable]::SequenceEqual($a1, $a2)                           00:00:00.0095582
3.78   0.023             -not (Compare-Object $a1 $a2 -SyncWindow 0)                          00:00:00.0227288

--- 1,000 elements: 1-position-different-only case (Note: on first run in a session, the LINQ method is now compiled and is much faster):

Factor Secs (1-run avg.) Command                                                              TimeSpan
------ ----------------- -------                                                              --------
1.00   0.000             [Linq.Enumerable]::SequenceEqual($a1, $a2)                           00:00:00.0001879
22.40  0.004             -not (Compare-Object $a1 $a2 -SyncWindow 0)                          00:00:00.0042097
24.86  0.005             -not (Compare-Object $a1 $a2 -SyncWindow 0 | Select-Object -first 1) 00:00:00.0046707
```

Optimizations for `Compare-Object -SyncWindow 0` shown above:

- Because `Compare-Object -SyncWindow 0` outputs *difference objects*, in the worst-case scenario it outputs `2 * N` objects - one pair of difference objects for each mismatched array position.

  - Piping to `Select-Object -First 1` so as to only output *one* difference object is an effective optimization in this case, but note that `Compare-Object` still creates all objects up front (it isn't optimized to recognize that with `-SyncWindow 0` it doesn't need to collect all input first).
- `-PassThru`, to avoid construction of the `[pscustomobject]` wrappers, can sometimes help *a little*, but ultimately isn't worth combining with the more important `Select-Object -First 1` optimization; the reason that it doesn't help more is that the passed-though objects are still *decorated with a `.SideIndicator` ETS property*, which is expensive too.

---

**Test code** that produced the above timings, which is based on the  `Time-Command` function available from [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/mklement0/9e1f13978620b09ab2d15da5535d1b27):

- Note: Assuming you have looked at the linked code to ensure that it is safe (which I can personally assure you of, but you should always check), you can install `Time-Command` directly as follows:

```
irm https://gist.github.com/mklement0/9e1f13978620b09ab2d15da5535d1b27/raw/Time-Command.ps1 | iex
```

```
foreach ($i in 1..2) {

  # Array size
  [int] $n = 1000
  
  # How many runs to average:
  # If you set this to 1 and $n is at around 1,300 or below, ONLY the very first
  # test result in a session will show 
  #   Compare-Object $a1 $a2 -SyncWindow 0 | Select-Object -first 1 
  # as the fastest method.
  # Once the LINQ method access is internally compiled, 
  # [Linq.Enumerable]::SequenceEqual() is dramatically faster, with any array size.
  $runs = 1

  # Construct the arrays to use.
  # Note: In order to be able to pass the arrays directly to [Linq.Enumerable]::SequenceEqual($a1, $a2),
  #       they must be strongly typed.
  switch ($i) {
    1 {
      Write-Host ('--- {0:N0} elements: ALL-positions-different case:' -f $n)
      # Construct the arrays so that Compare-Object will report 2 * N
      # difference objects.
      # This maximizes the Select-Object -First 1 optimization.
      [int[]] $a1 = 1..$n
      [int[]] $a2 = , 0 + 1..($n-1)
    }
    default {
      Write-Host  ('--- {0:N0} elements: 1-position-different-only case (Note: on first run in a session, the LINQ method is now compiled and is much faster):' -f $n)
      # Construct the arrays so that Compare-Object only outputs 2 difference objects.
      [int[]] $a1 = 1..$n
      [int[]] $a2 = 1..($n-1) + 42
    }
  }

  Time-Command -Count $runs {
    -not (Compare-Object $a1 $a2 -SyncWindow 0)
  },
  {
    -not (Compare-Object $a1 $a2 -SyncWindow 0 | Select-Object -first 1)
  },
  {
    [Linq.Enumerable]::SequenceEqual($a1, $a2)
  } | Out-Host

}
```