# Check if the first n bytes of a file are specific in Powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

How can I compare bytes from a file against a literal array of values?

```
$path = "C:\BinaryFile.bin"
$bytes = Get-Content -LiteralPath $path -Encoding byte -TotalCount 4 -ReadCount 4
if ($bytes -eq [0 1 2 3]) { # How to compare to expected bytes?
    Write-Output "OK: $bytes"
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe compare-object.  No output means equal.  Syncwindow 0 for exact order.

```
$path = 'file'
[byte[]](0..3) | set-content $path -Encoding Byte
$bytes = Get-Content $path -Encoding byte -TotalCount 4
if (! (compare-object $bytes 0,1,2,3 -syncwindow 0)) { 
    "OK: $bytes"
}
```

Or do a string comparision:

```
if ("0 1 2 3" -eq $bytes) {
    "OK: $bytes"
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain your solution and provide some real input out? Can it handle a moving window?

Answer (score 2):

PowerShell doesn't have a built-in operator for sequence equality, but you can write your own little utility function fit for this purpose:

```
function Test-ArrayEquals
{
    param([array]$ReferenceArray, [array]$DifferenceArray)

    if($ReferenceArray.Length -ne $DifferenceArray.Length){
        # not same length, not equal
        return $false
    }

    for($i = 0; $i -lt $ReferenceArray.Length; $i++){
        if($ReferenceArray[$i] -ne $DifferenceArray[$i]){
            # two aligned array members were found to not be equal
            return $false
        }
    }

    # we reached the end, array values must be equal
    return $true
}
```

Now you can do:

```
if (Test-ArrayEquals -ReferenceArray @(0, 1, 2, 3) -DifferenceArray $bytes) {
    # looks good!
}
```

Comment: Can you provide some example that show how this can be used to search a binary blob for a particular string of hex-bytes? For example, the `0x2b 0x41`?  Does your solution provide the search as *moving window*?

Comment: @not2qubit Not on its own, no, the code provided in my answer only compares two arrays of equal size. You could use it in conjunction with reading 1 byte into a bounded buffer from a file stream and then compare that to `0x2b,0x41` if you want. Feel free to [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)

Answer (score 1):

Arrays can be compared by `Compare-Object`. This reads the first four (4) bytes of a file and compares it to a literal array.

In Windows PowerShell 5.1:

```sh
Compare-Object `
    -ReferenceObject (Get-Content -Path '.\file.txt' -Encoding Byte -TotalCount 4) `
    -DifferenceObject @(97,100,115,102) -SyncWindow 0
```

In PowerShell Core 6.x+:

```sh
Compare-Object `
    -ReferenceObject (Get-Content -Path '.\file.txt' -AsByteStream -TotalCount 4) `
    -DifferenceObject @(97,100,115,102) -SyncWindow 0
```

EXAMPLE:

```sh
# Get-Content -Path .\firstfour.txt
adsf is the first four (4) bytes
dec 97,100,115,102
hex 61,64,73,66

# Format-Hex -Path .\firstfour.txt

   Label: C:\src\ttt\firstfour.txt

          Offset Bytes                                           Ascii
                 00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 0F
          ------ ----------------------------------------------- -----
0000000000000000 61 64 73 66 20 69 73 20 74 68 65 20 66 69 72 73 adsf is the firs
0000000000000010 74 20 66 6F 75 72 20 28 34 29 20 62 79 74 65 73 t four (4) bytes
0000000000000020 0D 0A 64 65 63 20 39 37 2C 31 30 30 2C 31 31 35 ��dec 97,100,115
0000000000000030 2C 31 30 32 0D 0A 68 65 78 20 36 31 2C 36 34 2C ,102��hex 61,64,
0000000000000040 37 33 2C 36 36                                  73,66

# Compare-Object `
     -ReferenceObject (Get-Content -Path '.\firstfour.txt' -AsByteStream -TotalCount 4) `
     -DifferenceObject @(97,100,115,102) -SyncWindow 0

# $null -eq (Compare-Object `
     -ReferenceObject (Get-Content -Path '.\firstfour.txt' -AsByteStream -TotalCount 4) `
     -DifferenceObject @(97,100,115,102) -SyncWindow 0)

True

# Get-Content -Path .\w.txt

line1
line2
line3
line4

# Format-Hex -Path .\w.txt

   Label: C:\src\ttt\w.txt

          Offset Bytes                                           Ascii
                 00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 0F
          ------ ----------------------------------------------- -----
0000000000000000 6C 69 6E 65 31 0D 0A 6C 69 6E 65 32 0D 0A 6C 69 line1��line2��li
0000000000000010 6E 65 33 0D 0A 6C 69 6E 65 34 0D 0A             ne3��line4��


# Compare-Object `
     -ReferenceObject (Get-Content -Path '.\w.txt' -AsByteStream -TotalCount 4) `
     -DifferenceObject @(97,100,115,102) -SyncWindow 0

InputObject SideIndicator
----------- -------------
         97 =>
        108 <=
        100 =>
        105 <=
        115 =>
        110 <=
        102 =>
        101 <=


# $null -eq (Compare-Object `
     -ReferenceObject (Get-Content -Path '.\w.txt' -AsByteStream -TotalCount 4) `
     -DifferenceObject @(97,100,115,102) -SyncWindow 0)

False
```

Comment: Thanks for updating (you still have the redundant `[0..3]`). By far the most typical uses case are: (a) _absence_ of `-SyncWindow`, in which case elements with the same value are considered present in both collections _irrespective of their position_. (b) `-SyncWindow 0`, in which case elements are only considered equal if they are in the _same_ position in both arrays. A _nonzero_ `-SyncWindow` value limits how many elements are considered to look for equal elements, and the resulting behavior is hard to reason about.

Comment: I don't understand how to use this... I get 2 columns with : `InputObject, SideIndicator`. Can you explain how this works with an example?

Comment: @not2qubit, an example is added.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers offer helpful solutions that work with array of *any* type.

Here's a **shortcut** that works in your case, that **compares the arrays *as strings***, taking advantage of how PowerShell *stringifies* arrays (see **limitations** below):

```
if ("$bytes" -eq '1 2 3' ) { # Be sure to use *decimal* values
    Write-Output "OK: $bytes"
}
```

**Limitations**:

PowerShell stringifies arrays by concatenating their (stringified) elements with spaces; e.g., `$bytes = 0x1, 0x2, 0xA; "$bytes"` becomes a string with verbatim value `1 2 10` (note how the *decimal* representations of the numbers are used).

Therefore, comparing arrays via their (PowerShell) string representations only works *robustly* if *both* the following conditions are met:

- The elements have unambiguous string representations (typically: .NET primitive types, such as numbers, and strings)
- No element's string representation has *embedded* spaces.

If the elements are *strings* and you want to compare them case-*sensitively*, use `-ceq` in lieu of `-eq`

---

**LINQ-based solution**

This solution, based on [`System.Linq.Enumerable.SequenceEqual()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Linq.Enumerable.SequenceEqual), works with all types.

Note the need for`[byte[]]` casts - which create strongly typed *copies* of the input arrays (which are themselves `[object[]]`-typed) - in order for the method call to work:

```
if ([Linq.Enumerable]::SequenceEqual([byte[]] $bytes, [byte[]] (1, 2, 3))) {
    Write-Output "OK: $bytes"
}
```

*Caveat*: It won't matter in this case, but in general it is worth noting that this method is *stricter* in terms of the element-by-element comparison than the PowerShell's equality tests as performed by [`Compare-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/compare-object) and the `-eq` operator: notably, string elements are compared case-*sensitively* by default. If you were to choose `[object[]]` as the cast above - to avoid the need to create *copies* of the arrays - numbers with the same value would only be considered equal if they're of the exact same type; notably, array literal `1, 2, 3` creates an `[object[]]` array with `[int]` values, not `[byte]` values.

On the plus side, the use of LINQ has the potential to perform much better than a `Compare-Object` solution - see the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64850192/45375) for more information.