# How do I evaluate if data or an error returned in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I am trying to test if a DNS zone exists in Powershell using the following cmdlet:

```
Get-DNSServerZone abc.com
```

That works great, but what I need to do now is turn that into a True/False evaluation depending on if there was an error or if there was data returned.

For example, this is a TRUE scenario:

```
$a = Get-DnsServerZone abc.com
$a

ZoneName                            ZoneType        IsAutoCreated   IsDsIntegrated  IsReverseLookupZone  IsSigned
--------                            --------        -------------   --------------  -------------------  --------
abc.com                            Secondary       False           False           False
```

Whereas this is a FALSE scenario:

```
$a = Get-DnsServerZone def.com
Get-DnsServerZone : The zone def.com was not found on server DNSSERVER1.
At line:1 char:6
+ $a = Get-DnsServerZone def.com
+      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (def.com:root/Microsoft/...S_DnsServerZone) [Get-DnsServerZone], CimException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : WIN32 9601,Get-DnsServerZone
```

What I'm struggling with is how to evaluate on that? In layman's terms I need to check if `$a` has actual data or not.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could wrap it in a try..catch:

```
try {
    Get-DNSServerZone abc.com -ErrorAction Stop
}
catch {
    Write-Warning "zone abc.com doesn't exist"
}
```

Or go the other way and ignore errors:

```
$a = Get-DNSServerZone abc.com -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
if (!$a) {
    Write-Warning "abc.com doesn't exist"
}
```

Answer (score 4):

> what I need to do now is turn that into a True/False evaluation depending on if there was an error or if there was data returned.

If you can simply *ignore* failures and don't need the object returned by `Get-DNSServerZone`, you can do the following:

```
$zoneExist = [bool] (Get-DNSServerZone abc.com -ErrorAction Ignore)
```

- `-ErrorAction Ignore` quietly ignores any (non-terminating) errors.

  - Passing `Ignore` to the [common `-ErrorAction` parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_CommonParameters#erroraction)) simply *discards* the error, whereas `SilentlyContinue`, while also not *outputting* an error, still *records* it in the [automatic `$Error` collection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#error), allowing later inspection.
  - You could also complement `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` with something like
    `-ErrorVariable err`, which would additionally record the command-specific errors in self-chosen variable `$err`, via the [common `-ErrorVariable` parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_CommonParameters#errorvariable).
- Cast `[bool]` maps `Get-DNSServerZone`'s output to `$true` (an object describing the zone was output) or `$false` (nothing was output (to the success output stream), because an error occurred), taking advantage of PowerShell's [implicit to-Boolean conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53108138/45375).

If you want the zone-description object too:

```
$zoneExist = [bool] ($zoneInfo = Get-DNSServerZone abc.com -ErrorAction Ignore)
```

---

An alternative is to capture the zone-information first, and to query the [automatic `$?` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#section-1) afterwards, which contains a Boolean value (`$true` or `$false`) that indicates whether the most recently executed statement caused any errors (whether suppressed or not).

```
$zoneInfo = Get-DNSServerZone abc.com -ErrorAction Ignore
$zoneExist = $?
```

Comment: Thank you very much!  This was extremely helpful in understanding error handling in PS. I had no idea you could query `$?` like that!

Comment: Glad to hear it was helpful, @DominicBrunetti; my pleasure. One more tip: only _terminating_ errors can be caught with `try` / `catch`, but you can promote non-terminating errors to terminating ones with `-ErrorAction Stop`, as in Theo's answer. For a comprehensive overview of PowerShell's surprisingly complex error handling, see [this GitHub docs issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell-Docs/issues/1583).