# Test-Path fails but doesn't do else

Tags: powershell, if-statement

I am trying to test several paths and if any fail, create the paths.

```
$subFolders = "$sortByProject$projectName\Originals", "$sortByProject$projectName\Pulled", "$sortByProject$projectName\Retouched", "$sortByProject$projectName\Uploaded"
if(!(Test-Path -Path "$sortByProject$projectName", "$subFolders")){
  New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path "$sortByProject$projectName", "$subFolders"
}
```

The test finds `"$sortByProject$projectName"` exists but `"$subFolders"` fails, so output appears like:

```
True
False
```

I would think since a false is returned, it would move to the new-item command and build all four requested folders (`.\originals, .\pulled, .\retouched` and `.\uploaded`). All the variable are properly named and return the desired path when called independently. I think the mess up is because there are multiple items assigned to `$subfolders`, but I don't understand why.

I also think this code is sloppy and would love to learn a better way to do a multiple path test and create any of the missing paths.

Comment: `$subfolders` is an array. If you surround it in quotes like `"$subfolders"` the array will be converted to string with all elements being space-delimited.

Comment: thanks, that was a typo. I think @jbsmith has offered a good & 'clean' solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to explicitly test the existence of your directory paths:

Just **use [`New-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/new-item)'s `-Force` switch in combination with `-ItemType Directory`, which will create the specified directories *on demand*** - including parent directories - while leaving existing directories alone (and returning directory-info objects describing the preexisting / newly created directories).

```
New-Item -Force -ItemType Directory -Path $subFolders
```

---

As for **what you tried**:

- Your [`Test-Path`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/test-path) command returns an *array* of Booleans, and **PowerShell considers any 2+-element array `$true` in a Boolean context** - irrespective of its element values; see the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53108138/45375) for a summary of the PowerShell's to-Boolean coercion rules.
- `-Path "$sortByProject$projectName", "$subFolders"` has two problems:

  - Not only is **double-quoting variable values passed as command arguments never *necessary* in PowerShell**, in the case of the *array* variable `$subFolders` using `"$subFolders"` turns the array into a *single string* containing the (stringified) elements separated *with spaces*.
  - If you correct this immediate problem - by using
    `-Path $sortByProject$projectName, $subFolders` - *another* problem is revealed: **you aren then in effect passing a *jagged* array**, whose first element is a string, and whose second element is a *nested array*, which would *break* the invocation.

    - Correcting this problem requires a perhaps non-obvious approach: you must use `+` rather than `,` in order to construct a *flat* array, which in turn requires that the LHS already be an array, which requires using the *unary* form of `,`, the [array constructor operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#comma-operator-), and *switching to an expression*, enclosed in `(...)`, the [grouping operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#grouping-operator--):
      `-Path (, $sortByProject$projectName + $subFolders)`

Answer (score 1):

```
$subfolders | where {-not (Test-Path $_)} | Foreach-Object { New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $_ }
```

Comment: this is perfect, it fixes the issue and doesn't try to build parts of the variable that may already exist i.e. no errors. Great work, thanks.

Comment: I thought this was working but i am getting an error stating the path is null, seems the $_ isnt maintaining the specific paths defined by $subfolders, any thoughts?