# IF there are folders older than 30 days

Tags: powershell, is-empty, isnullorempty

The script below finds folders older than 30 days. I just want to add a simple IF statement to say "There are not folders older than 30 days" if there are not any.  But I am not sure how to do that
Thank you

```
$Test = Get-ChildItem "\\Server\XFER\Cory" -Directory | 
    Sort LastWriteTime -Descending |
    Where-Object {($_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-30))} |
    Select-Object Name, LastWriteTime
```

Comment: If you want folders that are just older than 30 days, you should use `CreationTime`,  `LastWriteTime` is for modification. Other than that you just need to check your `$Test` variable - `if ($null -eq $Test) {  #do stuff }`.

Comment: `if(-not $Test){ "There are not folders older than 30 days" }`

Answer (score 1):

Your question boils down to this:
**In PowerShell, how can I determine if a command or expression produced any output?**

**In *almost* all cases, the following is sufficient**, as [Ash](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9164015/ash) suggests:

```
$Test = ...  # ... represents any command or expression
if ($null -eq $Test) { 'no output' }
```

---

**If you know that the command or expression** - when it does produce output - **only ever emits *non-numeric* and *non-Boolean* objects, you can simplify** to the following, as [Santiago Squarzon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15339544/santiago-squarzon) suggests, **relying on PowerShell's implicit to-Boolean coercion logic**, summarized in the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53108138/45375):

```
$Test = ...  # ... represents any command or expression
if (-not $Test) { 'no output' }
```

---

**If you're dealing with an (unusual) command that outputs a collection (array) *as a single object*** (as opposed to enumerating the collection and outputting each element separately, which is the normal pipeline behavior) and **you want to treat an empty collection object as lack of output too**:

```
$Test = ...  # ... represents any command or expression
# Caveat: Due to a bug, only works robustly with 
#         Set-StrictMode turned off (the default) 
#         or Set-StrictMode -Version 1 (not higher).
if ($Test.Count -eq 0) { 'no output' }
```

Note that this works even with `$null` output and a scalar output object (a single, non-collection object). In the interest of unified treatment of scalars and collections (arrays), PowerShell adds a `.Count` property even to scalars that themselves do not have it, so that scalars can be treated as if they were a single-element collection, also with respect to *indexing*; e.g. `(42).Count` is `1`, and `(42)[0]` is `42`; however, note that `$null.Count` is `0`. Such PowerShell engine-supplied type members are called [*intrinsic members*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Intrinsic_Members).

*Caveat*: Due to a long-standing bug - reported in [GitHub issue #2798](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/2798) and still present as of PowerShell 7.2 - accessing the intrinsic `.Count` property on objects that don't natively have it causes a statement-terminating *error* if [`Set-StrictMode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/set-strictmode) `-Version 2` or higher is in effect.

---

However, the tests above do not allow you **to distinguish between *no output at all* and a (single) `$null` value**, which **requires the following approach** - though do note that **actual `$null` output is *unusual* in PowerShell**:<sup>[1]</sup>

```
$Test = ...  # ... represents any command or expression
if ($null -eq $Test -and @($Test).Length -eq 0) { 'no output' }
```

This obscure test is necessary, because ***no output* in PowerShell is represented by the [`[System.Management.Automation.Internal.AutomationNull]::Value]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.Internal.AutomationNull.Value) singleton**, which **behaves like `$null` in *expression* contexts, but not in *enumeration* contexts** such as in a pipeline, including with `@(...)`, the [array-subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#array-subexpression-operator--), which returns an *empty* array for `[System.Management.Automation.Internal.AutomationNull]::Value]` (element count `0`) and a *single-element* array for `$null`.

While making the distinction between `$null` and  `[System.Management.Automation.Internal.AutomationNull]::Value` often isn't necessary, there are definitely cases when it is, given that their enumeration behavior differs. Being able to distinguish via a simple test such as `$Test -is [AutomationNull]` is the subject of [GitHub proposal #13465](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/13465).

---

<sup>[1] Returning `$null` from PowerShell commands (cmdlets, scripts, functions) is best avoided; instead, simply omit output commands. However, .NET API *methods* may still return `$null` and object *properties* may contain `$null` (even `[string]`-typed ones, and even in *PowerShell* `class` definitions - see [GitHub issue #7294](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/7294)).</sup>