# add-content to text logfile with Powershell after string is found

Tags: powershell

Unsuccessful with this code in appending the date to a flat text file when a pattern is matched in the file.  Verified that the pattern is found and but not able to get the add-content to function.
NOTE: the wait is used in order to wait until the keyword = Idle is written to the file.

my code is here:

```
$File = "AutoDE45oService_AP.$(get-date -Format yyMMdd).log"
        $Path = "C:\Users\user"
        $result = Get-ChildItem $Path -recurse | Where-Object { $_.Name -match $File } 
        $containsIdle = Get-Content $result.FullName -Tail 1 -Wait | Select-string -Pattern "Idle" -Quiet 
        If($containsIdle -contains $true)
{
    Add-Content $result.FullName -Value (Get-Date) -PassThru

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't make sense to combine [`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content) `-Wait` with [`Select-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string) `-Quiet`:

- `Get-Content -Wait` waits *indefinitely* for new content being added to the target file, if any. Waiting only stops in *exceptional* circumstances, namely if the target file is deleted, renamed, or moved.
- `Select-String -Quiet` only ever outputs *one* Boolean value indicating whether the pattern was found - even if additional input *also* contains that pattern.

Therefore, combining these two calls:

- only ever produces at most *one* output value - namely `$true` - for the *first* occurrence of the pattern found - even if content added to the file later also matches the pattern.
- keeps running indefinitely (unless you delete, rename or move the target file).

---

To solve your problem, you need two things:

- Omit `-Quiet` and act on the results in a [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object) that is *part of the same pipeline*:

  ```
  Get-Content -Wait ... | Select-String -Pattern ... | ForEach-Object { ... }
  ```
- Provide an external mechanism that terminates the command to keep it from running indefinitely:

  - When running *interactively*, pressing <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd> terminates execution.
  - For an automated, *timeout*-based termination mechanism, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68009810/45375) (to a related question of yours).

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure what part of your script you're trying to get into the log, but if you give something like this a shot, it might get better results than Add-Content.

```
Write-Output "The stuff you want in the log" | Out-File -FilePath $File -Append
```