# Why does '' not match '\s*'

Tags: powershell

Why does the empty item not match `'\s*'`? There are zero or more whitespace characters in the second item.

```
PS C:\> @('now','','is') | ?{ $_ -ne '' }
now
is
PS C:\> @('now','','is') | ?{ $_ -ne '\s*' }
now

is
```

Comment: 2nd item is $null not whitespace.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon, `$null -eq ''` produces `False`.

Comment: But `[string]::IsNullOrEmpty('')` yields `True` isn't it the same?

Comment: Right it's not the same, my bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to use the `-match` operator instead of the inequality operator you're currently using:

```
PS> @('now','','is') | ?{ $_ -match '\s*' }
now

is
```

However, since you're matching the empty string as well (and it may appear at any position in the input string), everything matches this regex. So perhaps you'd want to just match strings that are either empty or completely whitespace by *anchoring* the pattern:

```
PS> @('now','','is') | ?{ $_ -match '^\s*$' }

# ^ there is an empty line, it's just a bit invisible
```

Comment: Many thanks, @Joey. I thought I had tried this.

Comment: My bad on `''` being `$null` but what is `where-object` considering `''` to be? Since `@('now','','is') | ?{ $_ }` would already be filtering the empty string. I'm wondering what is happening under the hood.

Comment: Nicely done, though note that you've inverted the original logic. @SantiagoSquarzon, whatever `Where-Object` outputs is coerced to a Boolean, and `''` is implicitly `$false`, whereas any non-empty string (irrespective of its content) is implicitly `$true` - see the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53108138/45375) for a summary of PowerShell's to-Boolean coercion logic.