# Powershell import csv with $true and $false

Tags: powershell, type-conversion, import-csv

I am trying to learn how to import a csv in Powershell and create users out of it.
One of the values I need to import needs to be converted to a boolean. These values will only be `$true` or `false`.

My current code is

```
param([Parameter(Mandatory)][string] $inputfile)

$ADUsers = Import-csv $inputfile -Delimiter ';'

foreach ($User in $ADUsers) {
    $Name = $User.Name
    $SurName = $User.sn
    $GivenName = $User.Givenname
    $Email = $User.Email
    $SamAccountName = $User.samAccount
    $Path = $User.ParentOU
    $Password = $User.Password
    $Enabled = [System.Convert]::ToBoolean($User.Enabled)
    $ChangePasswordAtLogon = [System.Convert]::ToBoolean($User.mustChangePassword)
    $Description = $User.Description
    
    New-ADUser `
        -Name = $Name `
        -Surname =  $SurName `
        -GivenName = $GivenName `
        -EmailAddress = $Email `
        -SamAccountName = $SamAccountName `
        -Path = $Path `
        -AccountPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString $Password -AsPlainText -Force) `
        -Enabled = $Enabled `
        -ChangePasswordAtLogon = $ChangePasswordAtLogon `
        -Description = $Description
}
```

With the current code, my only problem (currently) seems to be I am unable to parse this string to a boolean. The error:
`Exception calling "ToBoolean" with "1" argument(s): "String was not recognized as a valid Boolean."`

Anyone who knows the best way to resolve this issue?

Comment: What are the values in the csv for these fields?

Comment: These values are `$true` or `$false` in the csv itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the CSV contains string values for `Enabled` and `ChangePasswordAtLogon` literally as `'$true'` or `'$false'`, you need to remove the dollar sign from it to be able to convert them into real Boolean values.

Also, I would suggest using [Splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting) the parameters to `New-ADUser`, so you can get rid of all those unneeded extra variables and especially those pesky backticks:

```
param([Parameter(Mandatory)][string] $inputfile)

$ADUsers = Import-Csv -Path $inputfile -Delimiter ';'

foreach ($User in $ADUsers) {
    $userParams = @{
        Name                  = $User.Name
        Surname               = $User.sn
        GivenName             = $User.Givenname
        EmailAddress          = $User.Email
        SamAccountName        = $User.samAccount
        Path                  = $User.ParentOU
        AccountPassword       = (ConvertTo-SecureString $User.Password -AsPlainText -Force)
        Description           = $User.Description
        # if these values in the CSV are '$true' or '$false' literally, remove the dollar sign
        Enabled               = [System.Convert]::ToBoolean($User.Enabled -replace '\$')
        ChangePasswordAtLogon = [System.Convert]::ToBoolean($User.mustChangePassword -replace '\$')
    }

    New-ADUser @userParams
}
```

Comment: Nicely done; `[bool]::Parse()` is a slightly more concise alternative.

Answer (score 1):

[Theo's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68963326/45375) provides an effective, streamlined solution; let me add some **background information**:

- The property values of the objects created from CSV data by [`Import-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-csv) are invariably *strings* (i.e. of type `[string]`).
- **You *fundamentally* cannot pass `[string]` values to `[bool]` or `[switch]` parameters** - even if those string values are `'True'` and `'False'`.

  - The simplest way to convert these values to `[bool]` is **`[bool]::Parse($stringContainingTrueOrFalse)`** (case does not matter, and the conversion works irrespective of what culture is in effect).
- **`[bool]` parameters**, which are rare, unlike the much more common `[switch]` parameters (see below), **accept *numbers* too**: `0` converts to `$false`, and any non-zero number to `$true`.
- **[`[switch]` parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Functions#switch-parameters) only accept actual `[bool]` values**, though note that they **rarely require an *explicit* argument**, because it is their *presence or absence* that implies their value; e.g., `-Force` is the same as `-Force:$true` (note the need to follow the parameter name with `:` in this case); and *not* specifying `-Force` is (typically) the same as
  `-Force:$false`; there are only two scenarios in which passing an explicit argument is needed:

  - To pass a switch *programmatically*, via a *variable* (e.g., `-Force:$value`)
  - To *override a preference variable* (e.g. `-Confirm:$false` to skip a confirmation prompt that would otherwise be shown based on the value of the `$ConfirmPreference` preference variable); in this specific case passing `$false` as an explicit argument does *more* than omitting the switch altogether would do.

---

Note:

The **above applies to *parameter* binding**.
By contrast, **in *expression contexts* strings (and other objects) *can* be cast or coerced to `[bool]`**, though the **behavior can be surprising**:

- An ***empty* string** evaluates to **`$false`**, whereas ***any* non-empty string** is **`$true`**, i.e. *irrespective of its specific content*.

Notably:

```sh
PS> [bool] 'False'
True # !! Evaluates to $true, because 'False' is a *non-empty* string.
```

In general, though, this behavior is helpful, as it **allows you to use strings directly as conditionals**; the following statements are equivalent:

```sh
if ($string.Length -gt 0) { 'non-empty' }

# Equivalent shorthand
if ($string) { 'non-empty' }
```

See the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53108138/45375) for an **overview of PowerShell's implicit to-Boolean conversion across all types**.

---

**Pitfall**, as of PowerShell 7.2:

While a *casting* a string to `[bool]` works as shown above, a **`[bool]` variable *type constraint* unexpectedly behaves like a *parameter declaration***:

That is, while you would expect `$var = [bool] 'foo'` to work the same as `[bool] $var = 'foo'` (aside from the latter locking the variably type in), the latter *fails*:

```sh
PS> $var = [bool] 'foo'  # OK: stores $true in $var

PS> [bool] $var =  'foo'  # !! FAILS
... Cannot convert value "System.String" to type "System.Boolean".
Boolean parameters accept only Boolean values and numbers, such as $True, $False, 1 or 0.
```

This problematic asymmetry is discussed in [GitHub issue #10426](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/10426).

Comment: Just read up on the issue discussed in the link posted. Kinda nice seeing one of the actual PowerShell creators comment (*Bruce*) interesting, and confusing indeed (*regarding the boolean issue).