# Powershell Item array not checking 0

Tags: sql, powershell

I am currently working on a PowerShell script that interacts with a SQL Server database, at one point I need to see if there is a customer by the same name in the table, as such I am running the following query from PowerShell.

NB. `Invoke-SQL` is a helper function which calls `Invoke-SQLCMD` with specified parameters and allows database calls to be turned off with a global `$Testing` flag

```
$Customercount = Invoke-SQL "SELECT Count(Cust_ID) FROM Customers WHERE Cust_Name LIKE '$CustName'"
```

This correctly returns an object which can be read with `$Customercount.itemarray` however when this returns a 0 the matching fails as per the example below.

```
PS> $CustName = "Joe Bloggs"
PS> $Customercount = Invoke-SQL "SELECT Count(Cust_ID) FROM Customers WHERE Cust_Name LIKE '$CustName'"
PS> $Customercount.itemarray
0
PS> if ($Customercount.itemarray -eq 0) {Write-Host "equals 0"}
PS> if ($Customercount.itemarray -eq '0') {Write-Host "equals 0"}
PS> if ($Customercount.itemarray -eq "0") {Write-Host "equals 0"}
PS> if ($Customercount.itemarray -eq $Null) {Write-Host "equals 0"}
PS> $CustName = "Gael Test" 
PS> $Customercount = Invoke-SQL "SELECT Count(Cust_ID) FROM Customers WHERE Cust_Name LIKE '$CustName'"
PS> $Customercount.itemarray
1
PS> if ($Customercount.itemarray -eq 1) {Write-Host "equals 1"}     
equals 1
PS>
```

I feel like I am missing something fundamental here but I haven't been able to place it, can anyone shed light on what I'm missing

Comment: This might also help https://www.sqlservercentral.com/forums/topic/powershell-itemarray

Answer (score 2):

If the left operarand is a collection, the comparison operator will work as a "filter" (see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-if?view=powershell-5.1#collection-operators)). So basically, what happens is, if `itemarray` contains a single zero, then the filter `-eq 0` will also return a single zero.

So, this ..

```
if ($Customercount.itemarray -eq 0)
```

basically becomes this..

```
if (@(0))
```

which, since it's only a single item, is evaluated as

```
if (0)
```

...which evaluates to `false`.

Comment: Indeed,`[bool] @(0)` is `$false`, which isn't exactly obvious. The bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53108138/45375) summarizes all the implicit to-Boolean conversion rule.

Comment: @mklement0 Despite all my love for Powershell, I hate it a little bit for giving me such Javascript vibes here

Comment: :).............