# In Powershell, get join-path to work with $null and empty string

Tags: powershell

Powershell 5 says "no way Jose", can't join path with null or empty string.  I say why not?  Is there a way to get join-path to be more "Flexible" without adding more if-else blocks?

```
    $its_in_the_path = $true
    #$its_in_the_path = $false

    if ($its_in_the_path) {
        $mydir = ""
    }
    else {
        $mydir "C:\tool\path  
    }

    $tool = join-path $mydir "runit.exe"
```

```
Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is an empty string.
daskljdhgfaklsuhfalhfluwherfluqwhrluq2345214723452345h2kjrwefqy345
At + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [frunsim], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorEmptyStringNotAllowed,frunsim
```

Answer (score 4):

`Join-Path` will not allow `$null` values or `[string]::Empty`. You can use [`Path.Combine Method`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine?view=net-5.0) for that:

```
PS \> [System.IO.Path]::Combine($null, "runit.exe")
runit.exe

PS \> [System.IO.Path]::Combine('C:\', 'Documents', "runit.exe")
C:\Documents\runit.exe
```

Answer (score 2):

[Santiago Squarzon's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69817879/45375) shows you how to work around the inability to pass `$null` or `''` to [`Join-Path`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/join-path) via direct use of a .NET API.

An alternative is to bypass both `Join-Path` and `[System.IO.Path]::Combine()` altogether and join the path components manually:

```sh
$tool = $mydir + ('', '\')[[bool] $mydir] + "runit.exe"
```

The above relies on the fact that both `$null` and `''` (the empty string), when coerced to a Boolean (`[bool]`), return `$false`, whereas any *nonempty* string returns `$true`. In turn, when used as an *array index* (`[...]`), `$false` maps to index `0`, and `$true` to `1` - see the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53108138/45375) for a summary of PowerShell's to-Boolean conversion rules.

---

In *PowerShell (Core) 7+* you can express this intent more clearly, using  `?:`, the [ternary conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#ternary-operator--if-true--if-false), relying on the fact that both `$null` and `''` also *implicitly* convert to `$false` in a Boolean context:

```sh
$tool = $mydir + ($mydir ? '\' : '') + "runit.exe"
```