# Class with hidden property breaking for-display formatting?

Tags: powershell, class

Related to this interesting question from [zett42](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71631192/15339544), seems like object instances with ***hidden or private*** properties *could be breaking the [for-display formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71631192/implicit-conversion-to-bool-of-struct-defined-in-c-sharp-fails-in-powershell/71632418?noredirect=1#comment126599208_71632418)* when piped to `Get-Member` as well as `Select-Object *`.

Hopefully someone could shed some light on this odd behavior.

```
class MyBool2 {
    hidden [bool] $Value
    
    MyBool2([bool] $Value) {
        $this.Value = $Value
    }

    [string] ToString() {
        return "$($this.Value)"
    }
}

$instance = [MyBool2] $true
```

Once the instance has been initialized, from our console:

```
PS /> $instance
True

PS /> $instance | Get-Member

   TypeName: MyBool2

Name        MemberType Definition
----        ---------- ----------
Equals      Method     bool Equals(System.Object obj)
GetHashCode Method     int GetHashCode()
GetType     Method     type GetType()
ToString    Method     string ToString()

PS /> $instance


PS /> $instance.ToString()
True
```

**NOTE**, this behavior is only observed in PowerShell Core. **Does not seem to be the case for Windows PowerShell**.

[GitHub Issue #17071](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/17071) has been submitted for anyone wanting to jump in.

Comment: Very strange indeed. That smells like a bug - `Get-Member` should be observing only, without side effects.

Comment: @zett42 it's not only `gm`, `select *` is breaking it too

Comment: Now the question is what [both](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/7dc4587014bfa22919c933607bf564f0ba53db2e/src/Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Utility/commands/utility/GetMember.cs#L61) [cmdlets](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/7dc4587014bfa22919c933607bf564f0ba53db2e/src/Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Utility/commands/utility/Select-Object.cs#L72) have in common that could cause this issue.

Comment: @zett42 I think it's best to have the PS Team check on this, submitted [GitHub Issue #17071](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/17071). Thanks zett