# Powershell logical function not executing when called from if statement

Tags: powershell, function, if-statement, logical-operators

Got a question why logical function is not executed or evaluated at all when called from if-statement. tried with powershell version 4 and 7 in windows, both failed.
i have already worked around on this, but curious how could this happen.

can anyone please help? not sure whether this is any environment setup related, or powershell grammar issue. any opinions would be appreciated.

```
# example 1:
```

```
    function isValidN{
      echo “isValidN is called”
      return 0 -lt 1;
    }
    function Main {
      if(isValidN){
        echo “t”
      }else{
        echo “f”
      }
    }
    Main;
    #result: it will not execute isValidN at all, it did not printout “isValidN is called”, Why?
```

```
#Example 2:
```

```
    function isValidN{
      echo “isValidN is called”
      return 0 -lt 1;
    }
    function Main {
     isValidN;
      if(isValidN){
        echo “t”
      }else{
        echo “f”
      }
    }
    Main;
    #result: the first isValidN call before if-statement would execute and printout “isValidN is called.”  However, the 2nd one in the if-statement NOT. Why?
```

Comment: _"it did not printout “isValidN is called”, Why?"_ because that output is captured here: `if(isValidN){` - if you want to see output to the console while executing that function you can consider using a different stream, such as the [Information Stream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_output_streams?view=powershell-7.2#long-description) (`Write-Host "isValidN is called"`)

Comment: Use `Write-Host` if you want to print straight to the host application - `echo` is an alias for `Write-Output`, so the `if` statement in your current code actually ends up evaluating `if(@("isValidN is called", $true))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The crucial information is in the helpful comments by [Santiago Squarzon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15339544/santiago-squarzon) and [Mathias R. Jessen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/712649/mathias-r-jessen), but let me break it down **conceptually**:

As will become clear later, your `isValidN` function *was* called in the `if` statement, but produced no *display* output.

- **PowerShell functions and scripts do not have *return values*** - they produce *output* that is typically written to the *success output stream*, PowerShell's analog to *stdout* (standard output).

  - In that sense, PowerShell functions more like a traditional *shell* rather than a typical programming language.
  - Unlike traditional shells, however, PowerShell offers *six* output streams, and targeting these streams is a way to output information that *isn't data*, such as debugging messages. Dedicated cmdlets exist to target each streams, as detailed in the conceptual [about_Output_Streams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Output_Streams) help topic.
- ***Any statement* in a function or script may produce output** - either *implicitly*, if output from a command call or the value of an expression isn't captured or redirected, or explicitly, with the - rarely necessary - [`Write-Output`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-output) cmdlet, for which `echo` is a built-in alias.

  - The implication is that any script or function can have an open-ended number (multiple) "return values".
  - By contrast, [`Write-Host`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-host) is meant for printing information to the *host* (display, terminal), and *bypasses* the success output stream (since version 5 of PowerShell, it writes to the information stream, which - as all streams do - goes to the host by default). As such, it is sometimes used as a quick way to provide debugging output, though it's generally preferable to use [`Write-Debug`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-debug) (for debugging only) or [`Write-Verbose`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-verbose) (to provide extended information to the user on demand), but note that making their output visible requires opt-in.
- **Unlike in other languages, `return` is *not* needed to output data** - unless there is a need to exit the scope at that point, its use is *optional* - and may be used independently of output statements; as *syntactic sugar*, data to output may be passed to `return`; e.g., `return 0 -lt 1` is short for the following two separate statements `0 -lt 1; return`: `0 -lt 1` outputs the value of the `-lt` operation, and `return` then exits the scope.

---

Applying the above to **what you tried**:

```
function isValidN {
      echo "isValidN is called"
      return 0 -lt 1
    }
```

is the equivalent of:

```
function isValidN {
      Write-Output "isValidN is called"
      Write-Output (0 -lt 1)
      return
    }
```

Or, using *implicit* output, and omitting the redundant `return` call, given that the scope is implicitly exited at the end of the function:

```
function isValidN {
      "isValidN is called"
      0 -lt 1
    }
```

Thus, your function outputs *two objects*: String `"isValidN is called"`, and the evaluation of `0 -lt 1`, which is `$true`

Using a command call (including scripts and functions) in an `if` conditional - captures *all* output from that command, so that:

```
if (isValidN) # ...
```

effectively becomes:

```
if (@("isValidN is called", $true)) # ...
```

That is, the two-object output from  function `isValidN`, when captured, turned into a two-element *array* (of type `[object[]]`), which was implicitly evaluated as a Boolean (`[bool]`) due to its use with `if`.

PowerShell allows *any* object to be converted to `[bool]`, and a 2+-element array *always* evaluates to `$true`, irrespective of its content - see the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53108138/45375) for a summary of PowerShell's to-Boolean conversion rules.

To summarize:

- What you meant to print to the *display*, `"isValidN is called"`, became *part of the function's output* ("return value"), "polluting" the function's output with incidental data, making the `if` conditional evaluate to `$true` *always*.
- Because `"isValidN is called"` was part of the output, and that output was *captured* (and consumed) by the `if` conditional, it never printed to the display.

---

What I assume **you *meant* do to**:

```
function isValidN {
      Write-Debug 'isValidN is called'
      0 -lt 1
    }

# Make Write-Debug output visible.
# To turn it back off:
#   $DebugPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'
$DebugPreference = 'Continue'

# Call the function
if (isValidN) { 't' } else { 'f' }
```

Output:

```
DEBUG: isValidN is called
t
```

Note:

- If you make a function or script an [*advanced*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Functions_Advanced) one, you can turn debugging output on on a per-command call basis, by passing the [common `-Debug` parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_CommonParameters#-debug), as an alternative to setting the [`$DebugPreference` preference variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Preference_Variables#debugpreference), which affects all commands in the current scope and descendant scopes.