# How to Skip Null Objects returned from CimInstance

Tags: powershell, null-conditional-operator

```
Get-CimInstance -ComputerName $pc -Class Win32_UserProfile | Where-Object { $_.LocalPath.split('\')[-1] -eq $compare } | Remove-CimInstance
```

Because some system profiles have empty values for LocalPath, I get the following:

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:52 char:88

Where-Object { $_.LocalPath.split('')[-1] -eq $compare })

Any way either first check for empty value and skip to next?

ty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In **PowerShell (Core) 7.1 and above**, you can use the [null-conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#null-conditional-operators--and-), **`?.`**:

```
Get-CimInstance -ComputerName $pc -Class Win32_UserProfile | 
  Where-Object { $_.LocalPath?.split('\')[-1] -eq $compare } | 
  Remove-CimInstance
```

As a **general caveat**:

- While `?.` works as expected with *properties*, with *variables* it unfortunately and unexpectedly requires the variable name to be enclosed in `{...}`, because - surprisingly - `?` is a legal character in a variable name.
- For instance, `Set-StrictMode -Version 2; $foo = $null; ${foo}?.ToUpper()` works, but using `$foo?.ToUpper()` instead does *not*, because PowerShell looks for a variable named `$foo?` (sic), which doesn't exist. Requesting that this counterintuitive behavior be changed - even though it is *technically* a breaking change - is the subject of [GitHub issue #14025](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/14025).

---

In **Windows PowerShell** you can use PowerShell's implicit to-Boolean conversion rules:

```
Get-CimInstance -ComputerName $pc -Class Win32_UserProfile | 
  Where-Object { $_.LocalPath -and $_.LocalPath.split('\')[-1] -eq $compare } | 
  Remove-CimInstance
```

- Due to use of `$_.LocalPath` as an operand with the [`-and`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Logical_Operators) operator, it is implicitly coerced to a Boolean, and `$null`  is coerced to `$false`; similarly, an *empty string* would yield `$false` - see the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53108138/45375) for a summary of PowerShell's to-Boolean conversion rules.
- Since `-and` short-circuits (as does `-or`), the RHS expression is never evaluated if `$_.LocalPath` yields `$false`, thereby avoiding the error.
- Note that [`-eq`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-eq) has higher precedence than `-and` (and `-or`), so no parentheses are needed around the RHS expression - see the conceptual [about_Operator_Precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operator_Precedence) help topic

Comment: If you're working with a string, you can also use `[string]::isNullOrEmpty($path)` to check if the path is, well, null or empty.

Comment: @GuyS, yes, but `$path` (in an _implied_ Boolean context, else use `[bool] $path`) is much simpler than `[string]::IsNullOrEmpty($path)` - and, as bonus for PowerShell users , they then don't have to learn about (clumsy) static methods such as `IsNullOrEmpty()`. If there's a chance that `$path` is  a type other than a string , `$path -like ''` will do. Note that `[string]`-typed variables and parameters in PowerShell are never `$null` (try `[string] $foo = $null; '' -eq $foo`, which yields `$true`, because `$null` was converted to `''`) - only object properties / values rom APIs can be.

Comment: Alternative way for PS 5.x, that avoids naming `$_.LocalPath` twice: `"$($_.LocalPath)".split('\')[-1] -eq $compare`