# Working with properties of variable in if statement

Tags: powershell, if-statement, boolean, powershell-5.1

I have coded this small script. Everything is working fine, the if-statement excluded.
It doesn't matter which value the variable $status results. The if-statement results always in the else condition.

Is it quite possible to work with the properties of a Cmdlet result in an if-statement?

```
$filepath = "C:\Scripts\Logs"
$date = Get-Date -Format "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss"

$tapejob = Get-VBRTapeJob -Name "GFS Backup to Tape"
$tapejob | Disable-VBRJob

$status = Get-VBRTapeJob -Name "GFS Backup to Tape"

if ($status.Enabled -eq "False") 
{"$date Der Backup To Tape Job wurde erfolgreich deaktiviert." | Out-File "$filepath\DisableTapeJobLog.txt" -Append}
elseif ($status.Enabled -eq "True") 
{"$date Der Backup To Tape Job wurde nicht erfolgreich deaktiviert." | Out-File "$filepath\DisableTapeJobLog.txt" -Append}
else 
{"$date Irgendwas stimmt hier nicht. :-)" | Out-File "$filepath\DisableTapeJobLog.txt" -Append}
```

Comment: What exactly are the values of `$status.Enabled`? If you run it through `get-member`, what is the type of `Enabled` (bool, string or something else)? Going to the else branch seems to suggest that `Enabled` might be `$null`, or maybe the property doesn't even exist.

Comment: The property `Enabled` provides a boolean value. If I query $status.Enabled I get the correct value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note:

- In order to detect the case where `$status.Enabled` is *not* a Boolean (such as `$null`, if no `.Enabled` property exists), use the following as the *first* `if` conditional:

  ```bash
  if ($status.Enabled -isnot [bool]) {
    "$date Irgendwas stimmt hier nicht. :-)" | Out-File "$filepath\DisableTapeJobLog.txt" -Append
  }
  ```
- The next section assumes that `$status.Enabled` returns a Boolean ([bool](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Boolean)); the complete `if` statement is in the bottom section.

---

Use `($status.Enabled -eq $false)` or, preferably and more succinctly, 
**`(-not $status.Enabled)`**

**Generally speaking**:

- There is *no*  need to compare a Boolean value against another value *explicitly* (see next point), but if you do, and that other value isn't already a Boolean, you need to understand how PowerShell converts it *to*  a Boolean - see next section.
- It's **best to use Boolean values *implicitly* in conditionals**; that is:

  - use `$someBooleanValue` in lieu of `$someBooleanValue -eq $true`
  - use `-not $someBooleanValue` in lieu of `$someBooleanValue -eq $false`
- As an aside: If you already know PowerShell's to-Boolean conversion rules, you can use *any* value implicitly *as a Boolean*, simply by using it as-is in a conditional and relying on PowerShell to convert it to a Boolean; e.g., 
  `$val = 'nonempty string'; if ($val) { 'yes' }` outputs `yes`, because any nonempty string is coerced to `$true` in a Boolean context (see below).

---

As for **what you tried**:

> `($status.Enabled -eq "False")`

**Comparing a *Boolean* value (`$true` or `$false`) to a *string* value such as `"False"` doesn't work as you might expect**:

Due to the LHS being a Boolean, PowerShell coerces the RHS to a Boolean too before comparing, and **PowerShell's to-Boolean conversion rules consider *any nonempty string* to be `$true`, *irrespective of its value***.

That is, `[bool] "False"` yields `$true`(!), because `"False"` is a nonempty string.

Therefore, your comparison is equivalent to `$status.Enabled -eq [bool] "False"`, which is the same as `$status.Enabled -eq $true`(!), i.e. the *opposite* of your intent.

---

See the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53108138/45375) for a summary of PowerShell's to-Boolean conversion rules.

---

To put it all together:

```bash
if ($status.Enabled -isnot [bool]) {
  "$date Irgendwas stimmt hier nicht. :-)" | Out-File "$filepath\DisableTapeJobLog.txt" -Append
}
elseif (-not $status.Enabled) {
  "$date Der Backup To Tape Job wurde erfolgreich deaktiviert." | Out-File "$filepath\DisableTapeJobLog.txt" -Append
}
else {
  "$date Der Backup To Tape Job wurde nicht erfolgreich deaktiviert." | Out-File "$filepath\DisableTapeJobLog.txt" -Append
}
```