# Simplest Powershell Import-Excel Question

Tags: excel, powershell, import

Output contents of Excel file where one or more columns are NOT empty.

Sample data:

[image]

Want to output just the Company, City, State and first Product

My lame attempt to code:

```
$File  = 'C:\test1.xlsx'
$data = Import-Excel -Path $File | Where-Object "Company" -ne " "
$data
```

Output is same as input, i.e. all lines appear

Answer (score 2):

Simple answer...........hours in the making:

```
$File  = 'C:\test1.xlsx'
$data = Import-Excel -Path $File | where {$_.Company} 
$data
```

Answer (score 0):

- Your [own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74756182/45375) is effective for column values that are either *strings* or *not filled in* (in which case they are `$null`):

  - `where {$_.Company}` relies on PowerShell's [implicit to-Boolean coercion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53108138/45375) and uses the built-in `where` alias of the [`Where-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object) cmdlet.
  - As such, you could simplify your solution by using [simplified syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Simplified_Syntax) (which is also what you used in your initial attempt, which mistakenly used `" "`, i.e. a *single space* for comparison):

    ```bash
    $File  = 'C:\test1.xlsx'
    $data = Import-Excel -Path $File | where Company
    $data
    ```
- A *generalized* solution that also works with columns that contain *numeric* data:

  ```bash
  $File  = 'C:\test1.xlsx'
  $data = Import-Excel -Path $File | where Company -notlike ''
  $data
  ```

  - PowerShell's aforementioned implicit to-Boolean coercion also considers *numeric* `0` to be `$false`, so `where Company` would also exclude column values that are `0`.
  - By using `-notlike ''`, the LHS is implicitly coerced to a *string*, which causes both `''` and `$null` to yield `$true`, but *not* numerical `0` values.