# Why does the -Match Operator sometimes return the matching strings and other times booleans?

Tags: powershell

This is my favourite operator in Powershell, but sometimes I feel like it despises me !!

Lets say I have a string like so in `$Clipboard`:

```
PowerShell Documentation - PowerShell | Microsoft Learn
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/

Welcome to Python.org
https://www.python.org/

GitHub
https://github.com/
```

Invoking:

```
$Clipboard.trim()  -split '\n' -NotMatch "^$"
```

Returns the actual strings that got matched, not booleans:

```
PowerShell Documentation - PowerShell | Microsoft Learn
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/
Welcome to Python.org
https://www.python.org/
GitHub
https://github.com/
```

Yet if I do something like this:

```
$Clipboard.trim()  -split '\n' -NotMatch "^$"| % {$Title = $_ -Match "https?:|//www\." 
$Title
}
```

I get booleans:

```
False
True
False
True
False
True
```

I am starting to avoid `-Match` now, send help please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a [***general* feature of PowerShell's *comparison* operators**](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#common-features):

- With a ***scalar* (single) LHS operand**, they return a [`[bool]`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Boolean) result (**`$true` or `$false`**).
- With an ***array* (collection) LHS operand**, they **act as *filters*** and **return *those LHS elements that match***, (invariably) as an array.

With respect to the [`-match`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-match-and--notmatch) operator, specifically, note that the [automatic `$Matches` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#matches), which contains information about *what* was matched, is only populated with a *scalar* LHS.

---

As [iRon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1701026/iron) points out, PowerShell's **implicit to-Boolean coercion rules** also allow you to **use operations with array-valued LHS *as conditionals***; e.g.:

```bash
# -> 'MATCH found',
# because the -match operation returns @('foo'), i.e.
# the subarray of matching items, and [bool] @('foo') is $true.
if (@('foo', 'bar') -match 'f') { 'MATCH found' } else { 'NO match' }

# -> 'NO match',
# because the -match operation returns @(), i.e. an *empty array,
# and [bool] @() is $false
if (@('foo', 'bar') -match 'x') { 'MATCH found' } else { 'NO match' }
```

However, there are **pitfalls**, namely when the filtering operation returns a ***single* result that happens to be `$false` when coerced to `[bool]`** Note that even though a single-element *array* is returned in that case, PowerShell treats it the same as its one and only element in this context:

```bash
# !! -> 'NO match', even though a match *was* found: 
# !! The -match operation returns @('') and [bool] @('') is the
# !! same as [bool] '' and therefore $false.
if (@('', 'bar') -match 'foo|^$') { 'MATCH found' } else { 'NO match' }

# !! -> 'NO match', even though a match *was* found: 
# !! The -eq operation returns @(0) and [bool] @(0) is 
# !! the same as [bool] 0 and therefore $false.
if (@(0, 1) -eq 0) { 'MATCH found' } else { 'NO match' }
```

If *two or more* results are returned, the coercion result is *always* `$true`, however, irrespective of the value of the array elements (analogous to how *no* results, i.e. an empty return array, always yields `$false`).

A **summary of PowerShell's to-Boolean conversion rules** is in the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53108138/45375).

Comment: Just looking at this I can see where I went wrong..I really need to take my time with the docs, but they can be so subtle too. Thanks allot for this I will go over it first in the morning for sure.

Comment: @hellen_dorandt89, 

Answer (score 2):

This is by design.  In your first example, where you get the strings back, you are passing a collection to `-match` and it is performing an implicit enumeration and returning the matched strings.  in you second example, you are enumerating the collection yourself and testing each item individually, hence the `Boolean` instead.

This behaviour is explicitly stated in the [-match operator help](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.3#matching-operators):

> When the input of these operators is a scalar value, they return a Boolean value. When the input is a collection of values, the operators return any matching members. If there are no matches in a collection, the operators return an empty array.