# Catch block does not print out Warning message into console after

Tags: powershell, try-catch

I am writing a simple script that checks for a local user account. I would like to use the try_catch error to handle errors but I am not able to figure out why the catch block in my script won't print out the warning message in the script. Any guidance is appreciated.

```
function checkAccount($user)
{
    try {
       Get-CimInstance Win32_UserAccount| Where-Object -Property Name -Contains $user |Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name -ErrorAction Stop
    }
    catch {
        Write-Warning -Message "Oops, ran into an issue"
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your error? Maybe it is not from `Select-Object` but from `Get-CimInstance`, so you should have `-ErrorAction Stop` there

Comment: it's a logical error, I was expecting ```Get-CimInstance... Where-Object... Select-Object -``` to throw a terminating error so the catch block catches and responds with a warning message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- There are *two* commands that could report non-terminating errors in your pipeline - `Get-CimInstance` and `Select-Object`<sup>[1]</sup> - so you should use `-ErrorAction Stop` with both.
- A simpler alternative is to **set the [`$ErrorActionPreference` preference variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Preference_Variables#erroractionpreference) to `'Stop'` for your entire function**:

```bash
function checkAccount($user)
{
    # Make all errors in this scope (and descendant scopes) (script)-terminating, 
    # which enables them to be caught with try / catch.
    $ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'
    try {
       Get-CimInstance Win32_UserAccount | 
         Where-Object -Property Name -eq $user | 
         Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
    }
    catch {
        Write-Warning -Message "Oops, ran into an issue"
    }
}
```

Also note that I've replaced `-Contains` with `-eq`, given that the [`-contains`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-contains-and--notcontains) operator is for testing if a *collection* contains a given value, whereas you're processing the user accounts *one by one*.
If, by contrast, your intent is to perform *substring* matching, use something `-like *$user*` instead.

**Caveat**:

- Advanced (cmdlet-like) functions imported from *script* [modules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Modules) do *not* see preference variables, unless they happen to be defined in the *global* scope - see [GitHub issue #4568](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4568) for a discussion of this problematic behavior.

---

If, by contrast, your intent was simply to ***test* if a given user account exists**, you could define your function as follows, using the [approved verb](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/cmdlet/approved-verbs-for-windows-powershell-commands) `Test` and - accordingly - making the function return a `[bool]` value (`$true` or `$false`):

```bash
function Test-Account($user)
{
    [bool] (
      Get-CimInstance Win32_UserAccount | 
         Where-Object -Property Name -eq $user
    )
}
```

- The commands involved will *not* report errors under normal conditions, so there's no need for explicit error handling.
- The `[bool]` cast takes advantage of PowerShell's to-Boolean conversion rules and the fact that a (non-primitive) object converts to `$true`, whereas *lack of output* or `$null` convert to `$false` - see the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53108138/45375) for a summary of the conversion rules.

---

<sup>[1] `Get-CimInstance` should normally only report an error for an invalid class name, and `Select-Object -ExpandProperty` only for a non-existent property name (unlike with `-Property`). The `Where-Object` call should never report an error, given that it doesn't enforce the existence of the specified property (however, with *invalid syntax* any cmdlet call would report a *statement-terminating* error).</sup>

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the non-terminating error. However, the script shared using  `$ErrorActionPreference` preference variable still provided a non-terminating error. Opted for an alternative solution that provides the desired output without having to use a try-catch block
`$result = Get-CimInstance Win32_UserAccount | 
     Where-Object -Property Name -eq $user | 
     Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
     if ($result -eq $user) {
     return "$user account found"
     } else {
        return "$user account not found"
     }`