# Get list of processes with a open window

Tags: powershell

Basically I was searching for solution to list all running processes which have open windows, and one solution was frequently mentioned (in PowerShell):

`gps | where {$_.mainwindowtitle}`

and I thought, this command listed firstly all running processes and filtered based on criterium mainwindowtitle == True?

However, there is no such a column called mainwindowtitle in the output of either 'gps (get-process)' or 'tasklist' (at least what as output was printed in the terminal) and is it invisible or is the way i understood the code wrong?

Any advice or suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code works as expected, and - thanks to the separation between *data* and *its display representation* in PowerShell's *object*-based pipeline - can easily be adapted to show what you want:

- The [`System.Diagnostics.Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Diagnostics.Process) *objects* returned by [`Get-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-process) (whose built-in alias is `gps`) have a `.MainWindowTitle` property that [`Where-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object) (whose built-in aliases are `where` and `?`) filters by.
- However, the **`.MainWindowTitle` property values are simply not *displayed* by default**, because the [formatting definitions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Format.ps1xml) for the output type do not define a display column for it (horizontal space in tables is limited, so only the most important properties are shown.

  - You can **select your own display columns by passing the names of the properties of interest to [`Format-Table`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/format-table)** (whose built-in alias is `ft`):

```bash
# Find all processes that have a main-window title and 
# show their process ID, name, and main-window title in a table.
Get-Process | 
  Where-Object MainWindowTitle | 
  Format-Table -Property Id, Name, MainWindowTitle
```

The most concise equivalent of the above, using aliases (recommended for *interactive* use only):

```bash
gps | ? MainWindowTitle | ft Id, Name, MainWindowTitle
```

Note:

- [Simplified syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Simplified_Syntax) is used in the `Where-Object` call.

  - That is, `MainWindowTitle` is equivalent to passing [script block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_blocks) `{ $_.MainWindowTitle }`
  - Even though the `.MainWindowTitle` property contains *strings*, they are implicitly evaluated *as Booleans* (`$true` or `$false`) by `Where-Object`, simply based on whether they are *empty* (`$false`) or not (`$true`).
    That is, `{ $_.MainWindowTitle }` is effectively the same as the more verbose `{ $_.MainWindowTitle -ne '' }`
    For a summary of PowerShell's implicit to-Boolean coercion logic, see the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53108138/45375).
- It is important to note that `Format-*` cmdlets should only ever be used for *display formatting*, and never to supply output for subsequent *programmatic* processing.

  - If you want to select a subset of properties *as data*, for later programmatic processing, use [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object) (whose built-in alias is `select`) instead.
  - See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55174715/45375) for more information.