# PowerShell -notlike not working in Where-Object

Tags: powershell, prtg, where-object

I'm struggling with this code:

`Get-Sensor -Name Ping | where {$_.Tags -like "Kat.A" -or $_.Tags -like "Kat.B" -or $_.Tags -like "Kat.C" -or $_.Tags -like "Kat.D"} | Select-Object Device, Tags`

I get these values via. Connect-PrtgServer. The output data for this is:

> DEVICENAME {Kat.C}
> DEVICENAME {Kat.B, C_OS_Win}
> DEVICENAME {Kat.A, pingsensor}
> DEVICENAME {Kat.A}
> DEVICENAME {Kat.A, pingsensor}
> DEVICENAME {Kat.D}
> DEVICENAME {Kat.D, pingsensor}
> DEVICENAME {Kat.B}

In this case, I want the other way around. I want to use -notlike to get all object, which doesn't have a "Kat.A, Kat.B, Kat.C or Kat.B" Tag. So I changed the code to:

`Get-Sensor -Name Ping | where {$_.Tags -notlike "Kat.A" -or $_.Tags -notlike "Kat.B" -or $_.Tags -notlike "Kat.C" -or $_.Tags -notlike "Kat.D"} | Select-Object Device, Tags`

But here is problem, that I get more values than needed:

> DEVICENAME {Kat.D, test}
> DEVICENAME {Kat.C, sql}
> DEVICENAME {Kat.D, domaincontroller}
> DEVICENAME {pingsensor, memberserver}
> DEVICENAME {pingsensor, memberserver}
> DEVICENAME {pingsensor, memberserver}
> DEVICENAME {pingsensor, memberserver}
> DEVICENAME {Kat.C}

I only need those four devices/tags which starts with pingsensor, because they don't contain a Kat.

Thank you for your upcoming help guys.

Best regards :)

Comment: Please add all details directly as pure text into the question, images is a poor conveyer here.

Comment: Classic logic inversion. You want to use `-and` instead of `-or` - if a result you're trying to exclude is `Kat.A` then `-notlike 'Kat.B'` is still true

Comment: With -and I also get more than the Kat. categories.

Comment: Could try -notin

Get-Sensor -Name Ping | Where-Object {$_.Tags -notin @("Kat.A","Kat.B","Kat.C","Kat.D") } | Select-Object Device, Tags

Comment: Doesn't work also. I really don't get why our attempts don't work. With -notin I get every Device with more than one tags. For example: DEVICENAME {KAT.D, test} all devices with DEVICENAME {KAT.A} are filtered. When I change to   Get-Sensor -Name Ping | Where-Object {$_.Tags -notin @("Kat.A*","Kat.B*","Kat.C*","Kat.D*") } | Select-Object Device, Tags I get all devices.

Comment: You use -like, but there's no * wildcards.  You use select, but there's no property headers.

Answer (score 0):

If this works:

```bash
$_.Tags -like "Kat.A" -or $_.Tags -like "Kat.B" -or $_.Tags -like "Kat.C" -or $_.Tags -like "Kat.D"`
```

and you want **to *negate* it, enclose the expression in `(...)` and prepend `-not`**:

```bash
-not ($_.Tags -like "Kat.A" -or $_.Tags -like "Kat.B" -or $_.Tags -like "Kat.C" -or $_.Tags -like "Kat.D")
```

However, since you're not using actual [wildcard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Wildcards) characters in your comparison patterns, there is no need for `-like` -just use `-eq` - or, preferably, given that `$_.Tags` seems to contain an *array* of values, use the [`-contains` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-contains-and--notcontains)

```bash
-not ($_.Tags -contains "Kat.A" -or $_.Tags -contains "Kat.B" -or $_.Tags -contains "Kat.C" -or $_.Tags -contains "Kat.D")
```

Note, however, that if wildcard matching were truly needed, `-contains` wouldn't work.

---

Note:

- **Switching from `... -like ... -or ...` to `... -notlike ... -and ...`** (analogously for `-eq` and `-ne`) **is *not* the equivalent negation if the LHS operands are *arrays***, which seems to be the case for you.
- The reason is that PowerShell's **[comparison operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators)** **act as *filters* with array-valued (list-like) LHS operands**:

  - That is, with an array as the LHS, they return the *sub-array of matching items* rather than a *Boolean* (`$true` or `$false`).
  - **Using an array *as if it were a Boolean*** - which PowerShell lets you do implicitly, because it can quietly coerce *any* data type to a Boolean<sup>[1]</sup> - **can have surprising results** - see the example below.

```bash
# Define an array to serve as the LHS of a -like operation.
$tags = 'Kat.A', 'Kat.B'

# BOTH -like operations evaluate to $true in the implied Boolean context of `if`, 
# because they both return a non-empty subarray of matching elements.
if ($tags    -like 'Kat.A') { 'yes' }
if ($tags -notlike 'Kat.A') { 'yes' }
```

Somewhat counterintuitively, this outputs `yes` *twice*.

That is, the results of the *array-filtering* operations, when interpreted as Booleans, were *both* true, because in effect the two `if` conditionals were equivalent to:

- `[bool] @('Kat.A')` -> `$true`
- `[bool] @('Kat.B')` -> also `$true`

By contrast, the ***containment operators***, **[`-contains`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-contains-and--notcontains)** and its operands-reversed counterpart, **[`-in`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-in-and--notin)**, whose very purpose is to operate on *arrays* (list-like collections), ***always* return a Boolean** (`$true` or `$false`), so it *is* possible to properly negate
`... -contains ... -or ...` as `... -notcontains ... -and ...`

---

<sup>[1] See the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53108138/45375) for a summary of the to-Boolean conversion rules.</sup>