# How to set mandatory attribute of a parameter to $true conditionally in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, parameters, powershell-core, powershell-7.3

The mandatory attribute accepts ScriptBlocks but as I've tested it and seen in other answers, it's always returning `$true`

```
function Test-Function {
    param (
        [Parameter (Position = 0)]
        [string]$First,

        [Parameter (Position = 1, Mandatory = ({
            return $false
        }))]
        [string]$Second
    )
    Write-Host "First: $First"
    Write-Host "Second: $Second"
}
Test-Function -First "boo"
```

I don't want to use Dynamic parameters because `Get-Help` doesn't show them (unless I'm missing something?), and I'm already using ParameterSets [a lot](https://github.com/HotCakeX/Harden-Windows-Security/tree/main/WDACConfig), so can't break their logic.

What are some other ways I can achieve what I want?

my goal is to first read from a user configuration file and if a value for a parameter is already available in that file then the parameter should turn from mandatory to optional.

Comment: You'd have to read the config file before the function is defined, or else look up how to implement dynamic parameters.

Comment: @Scepticalist `You'd have to read the config file before the function is defined` I did try that but it didn't work, do you have a working example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note:

- The next two sections make *general* observations.
- The bottom section shows an alternative solution to [your own](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76299824/45375).

---

> The `Mandatory` attribute accepts ScriptBlocks

It *technically* accepts a script block, but  passing one is *pointless*, given that the [property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.parameterattribute.mandatory)'s type is `[bool]`: `[bool] { <# whatever #> }` is *always `$true`*, as with any non-primitive object cast to `[bool]`.<sup>[1]</sup>

Only attributes explicitly designed to accept script blocks support them meaningfully, typically via the attribute *constructor* rather than (only) via one of its properties (e.g. `[ValidateScript({ <# whatever #> })]`)

---

> I don't want to use dynamic parameters because `Get-Help` doesn't show them

`Get-Help` (and the `-?` parameter) *do* show them, but *only if the runtime conditions for their addition are met*.

Therefore, the only way to *always* make a dynamic implementation of your `-Second` parameter show would be to add it *unconditionally* inside the `DynamicParam` block used to implement [dynamic parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Functions_Advanced_Parameters#dynamic-parameters), and to only make its `Mandatory` property dynamic, depending on runtime conditions.

However:

- Dynamic parameters are generally nontrivial to implement.
- Assigning a *default value* to a dynamic parameter - which is what you want - appears to be unsupported (assigning to the `.Value` property of a dynamic parameter is in effect quietly ignored).

---

The following alternative to your solution moves all processing into the `$(...)` [subexpression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#subexpression-operator--):

```bash
function Test-Function {
  param (
      [Parameter(Position = 0)]
      [string] $First
      ,
      [Parameter(Position = 1)]
      [ValidatePattern('^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+$')]
      [string] $Second = $(            
          # Try to obtain a default value and make sure one is available.
          $val = (Get-Content -Path "$env:USERPROFILE\.WDACConfig\UserConfigurations.json" | ConvertFrom-Json).policyname
          if ($null -eq $val) { 
            throw "A -Second argument is required or must be preconfigured."
          }
          # A default value is available:
          # Validate it based on the [ValidatePattern()] attribute.
          $validatePatternAttrib = $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Parameters['Second'].Attributes.Where({ $_ -is [System.Management.Automation.ValidatePatternAttribute]})
          if (-not [regex]::Match($val, $validatePatternAttrib.RegexPattern, $validatePatternAttrib.Options).Success) {
            throw ("The argument `"$val`" does not match the `"$($validatePatternAttrib.RegexPattern)`" pattern.", ($validatePatternAttrib.ErrorMessage -f $val))[[bool] $validatePatternAttrib.ErrorMessage]
          }
          $val # Output the default value to assign it to the parameter var.
      )
  )
  process {
      Write-Host "First: $First"
      Write-Host "Second: $Second"
  }
}
Test-Function -First "boo"
```

Note:

- While scoping the solution to the default-value code inside `$(...)` is desirable, there is added complexity due to having to dynamically apply the `[ValidatePattern()]` attribute to the default value (the code could be simplified; as shown it fully emulates what the `[ValidatePattern()]` does).
- Arguably, this added complexity shouldn't be necessary, as even a *default* value should automatically be subject to the same validation as an explicitly passed one. [GitHub issue #8795](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/8795) proposes just that.

---

<sup>[1] PowerShell allows implicit conversion to `[bool]` from *any* type. See the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53108138/45375) for a summary of the rules.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

So, I came up with this solution and seems to be working, haven't validated it with every possible scenario I have in mind but for now seems to be working, will update if I find any shortcoming.

```
function Test-Function {
    param (
        [string]$First,        
        [string]$Second = $(            
            ((Get-Content -Path "$env:USERPROFILE\.WDACConfig\UserConfigurations.json" | ConvertFrom-Json).policyname)                   
        )       
    )
    begin {
        if (!$Second) {
            throw "Variable Second was empty"
        }

    }
    process {
        Write-Host "First: $First"
        Write-Host "Second: $Second"
    }
}
Test-Function -First "boo"
```

**Caveat 1**: `ValidatePattern` attribute doesn't work with this method and fails to validate the default values assigned to the parameter from the file, but this will take care of it.

```
$UserConfig = (Get-Content -Path "$env:USERPROFILE\.WDACConfig\UserConfigurations.json" | ConvertFrom-Json)
function Test-Function {
    param (
        [parameter(ParameterSetName = "Installed AppXPackages", ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true)]
        [string]$First,
        
        [parameter(ParameterSetName = "Installed AppXPackages", ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true)]
        [string]$Second = $(            
            ($UserConfig.policyname)                   
        )       
    )
    begin {
        if (!$Second) {
            throw "Variable Second was empty"
        }
        elseif ($Second -notmatch '^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+$') {
            throw "The Supplemental Policy Name can only contain alphanumeric characters and spaces."
        }

    }
    process {
        Write-Host "First: $First"
        Write-Host "Second: $Second"
    }
}
Test-Function -First "boo" -Second "fdsf"
```