# Power shell: can't affect a value to variable When I use forEach

Tags: arrays, powershell, in-place

```
$variable = "test", "test1", "test2", "","test3"
Write-Host $variable
foreach($item in $variable)
{
if (-not $item -or $item -eq "") {
    $item ="N/A"
}
}
Write-Host $variable
```

1. this is the OuptPut: test test1 test2  test3
2. this is what I expect : test test1 test2 N/A test3

Answer (score 3):

Strings in .NET are immutable and passed by value - and when you assign a new value to `$item` it won't affect the existing string value extracted from `$variable` array.

Use a `for` loop to write back to the array:

```
for($i = 0; $i -lt $variable.Count; $i++) {
    if ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($variable[$i])) {
        $variable[$i] = "N/A"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To complement [Mathias helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76921823/45375), which shows *in-place modification* of an array, with an alternative that creates a *new* array, taking advantage of the fact that you can use entire statements *as expressions* in PowerShell, with the results getting automatically collected in an array (if there are two or more output objects).

```
$variable = "test", "test1", "test2", "","test3"

# Note:
#  If you want to ensure that $variable remains an array even if the loop 
#  outputs just *one* string, use:
#     [array] $variable = ... 
$variable = 
  foreach ($item in $variable) { if (-not $item) { 'N/A' } else { $item } }
```

Note:

- `-not $item` is sufficient to detect both an empty string an a `$null` value, based on PowerShell's automatic to-Boolean conversion rules, which are summarized in the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53108138/45375).
- While in-place updating is more memory-efficient, with smallish arrays creating a new one isn't a concern.