# Custom object array element with minimum / maximum value of some property

Tags: powershell

```
$CustomObjects = Get-Random -Count 7 -InputObject @(0..300) | ForEach-Object {$i = 0} {
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        id = ($i++)
        value = $_
    }
}

$min, $max = & {$Args[0].Minimum, $Args[0].Maximum} ($CustomObjects | ForEach-Object value | Measure-Object -Minimum -Maximum)

$CustomObjects | Format-Table id, value -RepeatHeader
$CustomObjects | Where-Object {$_.value -eq $min} | Format-Table id, value 
$CustomObjects | Where-Object {$_.value -eq $max} | Format-Table id, value
```

Are there more interesting options for finding the minimum / maximum?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could come up with a long list of valid PowerShell statements that all look slightly different and would yield the same result, but there's basically 2 ways:

- Sorting
- Keeping count

Obtaining min/max through sorting is exactly what it sounds like:

```
$min,$max = @($CustomObjects |Sort Value)[0,-1].Value
# or 
$min,$max = @($CustomObjects.Value |Sort)[0,-1]
```

Very succinct, easy to express - but might turn out to be slow on large collections

Obtaining min/max through keeping count is exactly what `Measure-Object` does:

```
$min,$max = [int]::MaxValue,[int]::MinValue
$CustomObjects |ForEach-Object {
  $min = [Math]::Min($_.Value, $min)
  $max = [Math]::Max($_.Value, $max)
}
```

Not as fancy, but faster for large collections

Answer (score 1):

[Mathias R. Jessen's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66870155/45375) shows elegant - but potentially wasteful in terms of *memory* - solutions ([`Sort-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/sort-object) of necessity needs to collect *all* input objects in memory so as to be able to determine the sort order).

Your own, [`Measure-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/measure-object)-based approach takes advantage of the *memory-throttling* property of the pipeline.

Due to use of PowerShell's *pipeline*, both approaches are likely to be *slow*, however - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38330961/45375) for a discussion.

A simple optimization of your approach is to make the `ForEach-Object value` pipeline segment unnecessary by passing `-Property value` to `Measure-Object`:

```sh
$CustomObjects | Measure-Object -Property value -Minimum -Maximum
```

The [`Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GenericMeasureInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GenericMeasureInfo) returned by this command has `.Minimum` and `.Maximum` properties, so there's no strict reason to create separate `$min` and `$max` variables, but if you wanted to:

```sh
$measureResult = $CustomObjects | Measure-Object -Property value -Minimum -Maximum
$min, $max = $measureResult.Minimum, $measureResult.Maximum
```

If you'd rather not create an auxiliary variable, you can use the following, which uses the [`.ForEach()` array method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Arrays#foreach):

```sh
$min, $max = ($CustomObjects | Measure-Object -Property value -Minimum -Maximum).
                ForEach({ $_.Minimum, $_.Maximum })
```